# Low-rep users should not be able to ask questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users

I have noticed that a lot of the questions I down-vote are from users with a very low reputation (and usually a randomly generated username). Perhaps these users shouldn't be able to ask questions until they have studied the site a little, and perhaps understand what good questions look like? The bar shouldn't be set very high -- maybe 10 points or so. Also, people with randomly generated usernames don't seem to be very community oriented -- perhaps they should be banned from asking questions altogether?

Comment: This is politically incorrect, so it will not be implemented.

Comment: Doesn't this **defeat the purpose** of being able to ask a question in the first place?

Comment: @rightfold slightly cross and tongue-in-cheek there. But true. Obviously.

Comment: -1 This would lead to a flood of users giving really poor answers or suggested edits in an attempt to gain the rep to ask their question: in other words, it would shift the quality problem from questions to answers.

Comment: Not to mention the flood of really bad usernames.

Comment: Even new users can write excellent questions. Contrary to recent ressentiments, newcomer questions are actually often well-received. There's no point in penalizing everyone just because a small minority can't be bothered nor educated.

Comment: Can't vote as dupe cos MSO vs MSE, but: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164377/155739

Comment: @rightfold -- no it isn't, and good community spirit there, glad you're not in charge. How did you get nearly 5k reputation without asking or answering any questions and not really voting on things?

Comment: There's enough users here. Close the door for awhile.

Comment: @mario it's not a small minority, and it's not a sin to ask people to understand the community they're joining before they mess it all up.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: By simultaneously being active on Stack Overflow, and existing in the physical reality in which rep is automatically shared between Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. Frakking genius, these meta rep whores!

Comment: "before they mess it all up". Like, you know, what you're doing on meta now?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - interesting speculation, but I think you're probably wrong. I think that it would chase away people who create accounts just to save themselves from googling a question, and only those people.

Comment: @sehe -- I know exactly what I'm doing, I'm participating in a community that I've been an active member of for over a year and trying to improve it by sharing my opinions. Thanks for the flame.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Go to his [stackoverflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1804599), not the meta one.

Comment: Hahaha. No irony. At all.

Comment: Ok, so I clicked the wrong link :-p

Comment: Meta-StackOverflow -- where did that come from? :)

Comment: @EngineerDollery: If you're going to blast people for supposedly not engaging themselves in this community, you should make _some_ attempt to pay attention yourself to what's going on around you. The Meta split was highly publicised, and not that long ago. You could at least have read the FAQ. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/155739

Comment: I know that -- I was joking, hence the smiley at the end of my comment. I suppose that small messages aren't good at communicating humor, sorry. And I wasn't trying to blast anyone

Comment: @EngineerDollery users already have to go through an interstitial page and click a checkbox to ask their question- it's a mistake to think they're just too lazy to type it into Google and that a small push will get them to do so. Rather, they don't realize they should Google, or are not good at phrasing their query or reading the results. If you think bad questions are a problem, how about "lol I dunno UR answer but upvote me sir I have urgent question" answers?

Comment: Consider how frequent Not An Answer posts are already, when people ask questions in answer boxes just because they don't know the difference. How do you think they'll react when a page says "you cannot ask, but please feel free to answer!"

Comment: @EngineerDollery You're not blasting anyone? Have a look at your question title, again, will you. Next up: your first comment to rightfold. How'd you miss the irony and humour in his line? (Note, he gave you the only upvote you have (had?))

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- I understand your point, but it is speculation. The current situation is, honestly, pissing me off a bit because I'm spending a lot of time dealing with poor questions. Isn't it better to risk pissing off people who have no intent of joining the community rather than pissing off people who have shown commitment and involvement?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I think most of them _are_ lazy: too lazy to go out and seek that knowledge and improve themselves. (I'd say all they have to do is to look at some existing questions for inspiration but, well, let's not go there.) However, the rest of your comment is so spot-on that I couldn't help but upvote ;)

Comment: @EngineerDollery: The problem is precisely that you risk pissing off people who may be _fantastic_ developers and potentially amazing community members, and making it so that they _never_ participate. Not every intelligent and knowledgeable developer is already on SO with high rep. But this has all been hashed out already; go to the MSE page I linked you to twice.

Comment: Ah the "I'm wasting time" argument again. Well then. Stop wasting it. It's almost always useless getting pissed off anyways.

Comment: Finally, requiring that users supply custom usernames rather than the default is getting the causation reversed. Yes, users who are more interested in contributing are more likely to provide usernames. But that doesn't mean forcing everyone to type in a username (which could just be gibberish) will make them involved

Comment: My opinion is that the most of new users came for a help. If the question is asked wrongly they will get a "slap" very quickly by the community and they will try harder next time.

Answer (score 87):

Let me tell you a little story about a forum I once tried to participate in. I do some work on the Oculus Rift, and Oculus has developer forums for discussing various topics. Now they had a spam problem in these forums, so they decided to solve that by requiring anybody who wanted to start a new thread to have posted in at least five other threads before they could do so.

You know what happened? People spammed in threads all over the site in order to be able to ask the question that they wanted to in a new thread. The whole thing turned into a mess, and I walked away really frustrated because I wasn't going to be able to ask the one question I wanted to.

People are desperate to have their questions answered, and they will do what they can to find a way to do this. One of the leading reasons I've observed for people creating sock puppets to vote for their own content is so that they can work around the question ban we impose on bad askers. They find all kinds of ways to create these fake accounts, which need 15 rep to upvote, from spamming bad edits until they get an account over that threshold to posting plagiarized content.

By forcing a reputation barrier, you will block good askers who simply don't participate much here and drive them away, while the really determined help vampires will find a way to work around this. I can tell you right now that we will see a load of garbage answers flooding the site if this was put in place, not to mention pure rage from good developers blocked by this.

I've even begun warming to the idea of allowing 1-rep users to comment, subject to [the addition of moderation tooling for watching over these comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue/226183#226183). While the reputation barrier we have in place for that was designed to keep spam and noise out, it also leads to piles and piles of non-answers and a lot of legitimate frustration from people who only want to provide follow-on comments.

A reputation barrier to asking questions is a really bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: It pains me a little but I feel like I'm starting to agree with you on the comments suggestion.

Comment: `Let me tell you a little story about a forum I once tried to participate in` When this didn't turn into a Fresh Prince reference, I must admit I was saddened. But you make a good point, nonetheless.

Comment: I'm being chatty but I am also a very early adopter of the Oculus and remember exactly what you are describing. That was SO AWFUL.

Answer (score 20):

Regarding question-asking barriers, the problem you identify is a real one, and the solution you propose is clearly well-intentioned; or, at least, [I've suggested this myself in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164377/155739). However it was pointed out to me then and now it's been pointed out to you, also, that these solutions just shift the problem rather than fixing it.

As for usernames, again I can see where you're coming from, but forcing people to select a username and ensure that it does not match the regex `/user(\d+)/` is not going to make people more community-oriented; they will remain just as lazy and selfish as they were before, but now with added stupidity in their usernames.

I long ago resigned myself to the conclusion that these issues are fundamentally unfixable in an open system.

At least it's really very easy to get a question-asking ban if you're downvoted to oblivion a couple of times ;) Sure, that doesn't fix the initial poor questions, but unless you're going to force somebody to take a test and appoint somebody else to be Lord High Test Giver and decide who gets to ask questions and who does not, you can't solve that either without simply banning *all* new users ever from asking any questions ever again.

Comment: The shift in problems is speculative, not proved.

Comment: @EngineerDollery It's also blindingly bloody obvious.

Comment: And my code is obviously always right, so why do I need to write tests...

Comment: Testing is not done in production environments, though.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: No, your code is not obviously always right. Code obviously will always have bugs. That has nothing to do with this whatsoever. It's a well-established pattern that people who do not care about the integrity/neatness of SO will find a way around any barrier you put up, and that's been proven time and time again. People who post comments as answers "because they don't have enough rep yet" are the most obvious example. This would be no different. It's psychology/social studies, not computer programming or QA.

Comment: @sehe -- testing is almost always done in production. Take a look at the new Samsung Galaxy S5 if you doubt that.

Comment: Sorry @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I was overreaching for a metaphor. I simply meant that what seems blindingly obvious often isn't right. That's what science, and experimentation is for. That's why we right tests, to defend us against what is obvious, and it's what I'm suggesting here -- that we experiment, rather than speculate. Changes don't need to be slow in coming, nor do they need to be set in stone if they're not working.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: I already told you why and how we've seen it before. And because it's social science, it's been seen millions of times on a global scale and been well documented. You can't say the same about the code you wrote yesterday and are now running in production for the first time.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I don't know what side you were trying to argue there. I bet the revenue generated in vehicle sales, infrastructure projects and pharmaceutical expenditures will dwarf the numbers for smart phones running open-source operating systems, e.g.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Science is about testing, but within reason, because it's also about generalizing from the generic particular. If every other time they've implemented a bar to posting questions, people have found workarounds which allowed them to post questions anyway (e.g. banned users creating new accounts), it's not unfair, unreasonable, or unscientific to say that new users will jump through hoops to post their question, but they will do so with disregard for the rules and the community. That's an educated guess with evidentiary support, not a wildly anecdotal claim.

Answer (score 18):

> Low-rep users should not be able to ask questions

I totally disagree. Why not? Just because they have low reputation doesn't mean they're dumb and not capable of asking good questions. In fact, new users contribute to a lot of good quality questions. If we impose such a limit over new users, we're essentially blocking good content too.

> Also, people with randomly generated usernames don't seem to be very community oriented -- perhaps they should be banned from asking questions altogether?

All the usernames are randomly generated and are of the format userXXXXX. That's the same over the entire network. Why should username be a factor when you judge the quality of a question? **Don't judge a person by his looks, username or profile picture.** In fact, don't judge him at all. Just look at the questions/answers he posts and give them the appropriate treatment.

### Proof that users with default usernames *can* contribute

Take a look at this [data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158328/top-users-who-havent-changed-their-username):

1. [user113716](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716) - 133243 reputation
2. [user414076](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414076) - 55136 reputation
3. [user370305](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370305) - 41870 reputation
4. [user7116](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7116) - 38857 reputation
5. [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112) - 29139 reputation
6. [user187291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187291) - 27816 reputation
7. [user225312](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225312) - 20192 reputation
8. [user246408](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246408) - 19412 reputation
9. [user568109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568109) - 17151 reputation
10. [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740) - 13490 reputation

Comment: My username wasn't randomly generated - It's the name I chose when I set up my account -- yours too by the look of it.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: Yeah, so? Why should it matter at all? Are you saying people with randomly generated usernames are incapable of asking good questions?

Comment: I'm saying that they're unlikely to be part of a community. I haven't seen many high-reputation accounts with random usernames, and good quality questions seem to come from high-rep accounts. (I'm counting anything above 20 as high in this case -- like I said, I set the bar quite low).

Comment: Also, people and books, are *always* judged by their covers. How else are you meant to judge it? That's what judging means, and everyone is judgmental. To assume otherwise is dishonest.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: See the updated answer. I've added *proof* for you :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Even more interesting, I know `userXXXXX` that would consistently CW all their answers, or post the payload in a comment. You'd never know by looking at the rep.

Comment: 3k more reputation and I would be on the list :'(

Comment: @EngineerDollery You are user:2051454, according to the system. Just another number, as far as The Man is concerned.

Answer (score 6):

If you ask enough low-quality questions, you can be restricted from asking more, yes. It is already in place, at least in stack overflow proper.

Comment: That wasn't my suggestion. I'm suggesting that you must have earned some rep before posting your first question.

Comment: @Engineer: And he's telling you about the system that is already in place to address this concern, at least in part.

Comment: Ok, I understand your question better. And yes, that proposal would effectively cut off stack overflow from the majority of users. If only serious, non trivial questions are allowed, and you must have answered some of these already (well enough to earn rep), then you are cutting off a large amount of users. Granted, the "least valuable" set, but essentially it would become more and more difficult over time to "break in", as only existing, experienced users asking questions that they themselves were unable to figure out. This would block out all beginners from participating in stack overflow.

Comment: I realize that I'm opening myself up for serious bombardment here, but personally, I don't value the presence of beginners on SO. I'd rather steer it towards becoming a professional community.

Comment: Perhaps a higher bar of entry could increase the quality for the site in general, but you also have to consider how tremendously valuable that participation is for those new users. Stack overflow has made an enormous contribution to the careers of many people, who not so long ago had NOTHING to offer the community as a whole. So while your basic premise of more exclusivity/higher quality is true to a point, I think the losses overall would outweigh the benefits. The exceptional questions and users are drawn to the top very quickly by the rating systems anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to ask good questions, especially not if you are not communicating in your main language. There has to be a place where new users can learn the art of providing enough information to make their question understandable. We should be willing to provide some support on this, as everyone has been new on the forum at some point.

I do post comments to new user questions that are not clear, in order to make them understand what makes a good question. This is not as interesting as answering a technical problem, but it will educate users and help them to learn. In my opinion this should be highly valued as one of the points of StackOverflow is to learn, to get better. In my experience there is no better way to do this than to ask questions. As writing code this is an interactive process and you must be allowed to make mistakes in order to get it right.