# A tiny barrier to entry

Tags: feature-request, tags

**The Problem**

The site is struggling to maintain its identity and usefulness as it is increasingly flooded with questions (and answer) from non-programmers. Several Meta users have been working to bring attention to the problem:

[Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/749181)

> Knuth bless 'em for trying to do something fantastic with their lives, [but] they've become quite a drain on us and other resources.

and

> You're seeing something I've been talking about for a while, and it boils down to the motivation people find to become programmers...Folks are entering this field not because they have any real drive, love or talent for the craft, but because they want the financial security and social notoriety that comes with the job. They're not ever going to be good programmers because they probably aren't ever going to think like one.

[Tomalak](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

> I'm seeing a rapid trend towards worse and worse question quality. It gets to the point where I'm asking myself *"Why did I even help this guy? He neither has the will nor the capacity to understand the answer; I have just been wasting my time". That happens more and more often lately and is pretty frustrating.

[Brian Roach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252049#comment6470_252049)

> The influx of cargo-culting morons I constantly have to dismiss from interviews because they can't actually solve problems / write code pretty much reflects the problem. SO has turned into 98% "Give me teh fish" with people who don't care about the site gleefully handing out fish because of imaginary internet points. That's not what the core values and guidelines of the site supposedly state / represent.

The established users are increasingly becoming janitors. In my opinion, the increasing load of housekeeping work is a tedious distraction from the real purpose of the site; it leads to discontent and, in too many cases, abandonment of the site altogether.

[Gerrat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252049#comment13240_252049)

> SO wants eyeballs (it's a business - more eyeballs = more advertising $), but is killing the golden goose with its current policies. Discouraging new users from posting trivial questions is strictly a good thing. In order to get answers, they will be forced to (heaven forbid) actually Google their question, and the regular users can focus more of their time on crafting higher quality questions and answers

**The Caveat**

The above is only a problem if the "old" identity of StackOverflow is the preferred one. Who do we wish to cater to? Is the staff and community willing to allow the site to become an interactive debugging service in addition to an authoritative question/answer library, or are the "find my bug" and "gimme teh codez" questions off topic? I suspect that there are considerable differences of opinion on this topic.

**Related initiatives**

Tim Post and Shog9 are working to increase the negative consquences of abusing the system. (See paragraph 5 and 6 [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/749181))

[Filter low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions)

[Give high-rep users extra weight on close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes)

Many of these initiatives have merit, but they all focus on fixing a problem after it has occured: they would deal with bad questions after they have been posted. I wish to propose a solution that would ever-so-slightly raise the barrier to entry, to prevent many bad questions from ever being posted.

**A Potential Solution: Introduce an very basic tag-based literacy test**

I propose that we introduce a method of determining whether a question asker has a basic level of skill in the tag that they apply to their question. The community can propose and vote on simple tag-specific questions. In turn, that chosen question will be presented the first time a user attempts to attach the tag to a question. For example, if a user attempts to attach the PHP tag to a question, s/he will be presented with this task:

```
Correct the syntax error in this line of code:

echo (Enter your name');
```

or a multiple choice question:

```
Which line does not contain a syntax error?

A. echo (Enter your name');
B. echo ("Enter your name');
C. echo ('Enter your name');
```

Such questions will perform a simple function: distinguish between people who understand the fundamental elements of their own questions and perform basic debugging, and those who do not.

Initially, not all tags will have such questions. I propose that we allow people to use such tags without the check. When the established users in the tags wish to deal with the influx of problematic questions, they can come to Meta to propose and discuss the type of question that would be sufficient to act as a slight barrier to entry with the goal of improving the quality of questions in the tag.

This suggestion will not limit the ability of non-technical people to post question: they will simply have to settle for using tags that they understand. We can even consider establishing a list of canonical sources or question/answer pairs to present to users who fail the literacy test for a given tag in hopes that they will be able to educate themselves.

Implementation will not be trivial: It will require SE developers to implement the new functionality, and will require the input of Meta users to develop and refine the questions. The benefits will be manifold: individual tags will become more focused and useful when low-quality questions are automatically prevented. Site regulars will spend less time moderating and (potentially) more time focusing on the main mission: building a library of detailed answers to every question about programming. The site will become cleaner and more useful as users understand its true purpose.

Comment: There's a basic fallacy in trying to force the world to confirm to one's views, as there will always be others who disagree about many specific calls.  A far superior solution would be **customized filtering** so that picky users can choose to view a version of the site meeting their preferences.

Comment: @Chris, your speed reading skill must be well beyond that of mere mortals. Nevertheless, you'll find that this suggestion does indeed allow for just that type of filtering: people who are unable (or unwilling) to pass the tag-based test are able to post questions elsewhere on the site. Anyone wishing to view them still may, but are also allowed to simply view questions in their selected tags if they prefer.

Comment: No, your fundamental mistake is trying to put a filter **on authors**.  Ultimately, the filter must go **on readers** as different readers **have irreconcilably different needs**.  This has always been true, the Internet merely means the distinction is no longer possible to ignore.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think our difference of opinion is fundamental indeed. I still believe that there are types of questions that are simply unacceptable on this site, not based on the reader's preference or skillset, but based on the scope and purpose of the site. I addressed this view in the "Caveat" section.

Comment: The fate of [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253491/2235132) didn't deter you from writing this post?  It feels odd that the obvious is so hard to understand.

Comment: @devnull Denis is a bit (though perhaps not much) farther down the road to defeatism. I still have a glimmer of hope that there are enough people interested in turning the ship around.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins People on-board can do little to turn the ship around unless the captain is willing.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, that's a good find. It differs slightly in implementation, but the spirit is the same. Thanks for finding it. EDIT: I just noted that I participated on that question. Memory continues to fade with age... On a weird note, this is the first time I have ever had to vote to close my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: @George Cummins: lol I just noticed that myself, *after* you mentioned it.

Comment: I don't like the barrier to entry approach. I think we should increase the burden on askers, but only to form a good question, not to exclude rank novices from asking at all. And, I think we should guide them through the process, not demand that they already posses the skill needed. This is my contribution to addressing the issue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions/253317#253317

Answer (score -8):

Interesting feature request.  It's definitely a problem to have so many duplicates of basic questions, as well as questions that obviously show poor research and effort.

I disagree with the specific proposal, however—some of the right questions are **caused** by the problem of some people failing to understand the tags.  For example, a beginner may fail to realize that a bug is Android-specific or inherent in the basic Java code.

Alternatively, I propose creating a reputation minimum of greater than 1 for posting questions.  Most of the good questions are indeed posted by Users who know the ropes of the site.  It doesn't have to be a high minimum—Users who are trusted on other Stack Exchange sites should be reasonable candidates for being trustworthy on Stack Overflow.  Allowing the critical amount of reputation to be gained from, say, flagging posts would give Users enough of a feel for the site to be allowed to ask their own questions.

Comment: A reputation-based restriction has been proposed before. Here are a couple of recent examples: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253168/low-rep-users-should-not-be-able-to-ask-questions/ and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252061/what-effect-would-introducing-a-small-barrier-for-new-users-to-ask-a-question-ha

Comment: Also, a) you don't gain reputation from flagging posts, and b) users with <15 rep can't flag posts. Did you mean suggesting edits?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I know you don't gain reputation from flagging posts but with the increased "barrier to entry" for answering, I was proposing an alternative way of gaining reputation that would verify beginners know/are learning the ropes of the site.

Comment: @La-comadreja: people who are still learning the ropes of the site (but who are desperately attempting to gain the ability to ask their question) are the last people we want flagging. This would greatly increase the invalid flag percentage and workload on moderators and >10K users.

Comment: @DavidRobinson do you already see a large number of invalid flags?  This might not apply if declined flags were to decrease reputation.

Comment: @La-comadreja: That in turn would decrease the incentive to cast valid flags would happen. Right now the flagging system has its problems, but one of the reasons it works as well as it does is that people casting flags do so because they care about the site (aside from a few badges). Mixing flags and reputation is a very dangerous idea.