# Would asking a question at a reputation cost help improve quality / durability for SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, new-users, question-quality

In my opinion, a lot of questions (probably because of the massive amount of them) don't really get the **attention** they deserve:

1. A lot of them don't get *answered* at all.
2. Questions deserving to be closed don't get closed in a timely manner because of low views.
3. Some questions suffer from bad answers which don't get downvoted or commented on (again, I guess mainly because of low views, since the last refresh hundreds of new questions have probably been posted).

**I was wondering if the following mechanism could help:**

What if the simple act of asking a question would imply a cost of (e.g.) 10 reputation?

If your question is well-formed, with our kind-hearted community it will be easy enough to get yourself two upvotes to negate that.

You would also still only need a single upvoted answer before you bought yourself enough "credit" to ask a question. Maybe you could get three "free" questions when joining the site (to avoid raising the bar to entry).

At this point, I believe any mechanism that would lower the sheer amount of questions being posted would be beneficial to the site (without it becoming hard to join or elitist in any way off course).

Comment: I like this idea. Tim Post [recently mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/) that they're similarly looking into some kind of pay-your-way for users who've gotten themselves q-banned. I thought he talked about it elsewhere, too, but I can't find that right now.

Comment: I wonder how many question would not be asked if you had three free questions and from the fourth you would have to pay 10 rep. Probably not so many. I just glanced through the newest dozen or so downvoted questions on the iphone tag. Exactly one of those would be affected. The others where either one of the first three or the user had enough rep to spent 10 rep on each question

Comment: This might sound good in principle, but I am not sure how much it would help.  I was researching a certain dupe type and was amazed at how many users were never seen after their first question.  Buying in with answers wont help because someone who asks crap questions will likely give crappier answers; giving them 3 freebees does nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks @all for commenting! I don't necessarily think 3 freebees is the correct `magic number` (maybe the `bar to entry` should be higher, or different) but I believe applying this principle is still interesting. One of the sites I frequent often (because of my arcade pcb hobby) has a 10 (non spam) post bar to entry for gaining access to the `tech/repair` and `for sale` parts of the site and that has been working fine for them (not to be flooded with repair help questions). People can get *plenty* of value from SO, even if it would require them to put a bit more (virtual) effort in.

Comment: I share the sentiment that the noise ratio is a little to high.  Subscribing to tags helps, but it might be a little more manageable if the front question page functioned a little more like reddit where upvoted answers continued to bubble to the top.

Comment: I **do** sort of like the principle, but even one free question would leave the barn door open to a great many people asking [bad questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23858414/1070452).  Requiring `N` upvoted answers could help, but would actually encourage more garbage (in the form of A's rather than Q's) from those determined to post their question. It might almost assure they never get the right to Ask from dnvotes.  I would kind of like a waiting period: you cant post a Question for N days (or maybe hours).  Maybe that would get them to Google.

Comment: [Similar proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252534#252534) (which I personally prefer): "*Put questions (and possibly answers) (at least those by low-reputation users, e.g. < 1k rep, or possibly even more) into a review queue before getting seen by the general public.*"

Comment: @RandomSeed: This review queue is a very bad idea; we are struggling to keep-up with the close-queue, so I don't see how we could keep up with this new review-queue which is bound to have more traffic. And if you open up the review-queue to more people, then essentially you are just making it public.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I believe with such a filter, a new user would be able to post only *one* low-quality post, whereas s/he currently is able to post as much crap as she wants (cluttering the close-queue) until s/he gets flagged. This supposes that a user wouldn't be able to submit anything until her previous post is reviewed.

Comment: I humbly disagree with you. What about a new user who is new to programming. I have seen users without ban but with over 10 questions of "0" score. AND, another thing came to my mind from new user's point of view. Consider two friends talking about SO: _In earlier days of SO you could ask any number of questions, but now, they are forcing you to use their site in order to ask more than 3 questions._

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've already expressed my disagreement with having a reputation barrier for question-asking [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253179/19679), which is the only way that I see this proposal being effective. Many if not most of the worst questions we get every day are from low-rep users. Even if you give three "free" questions to them, the question ban kicks in at the third terrible question, so we're back to where we are today.

I've been saying this quite a bit lately, but I really am beginning to believe that for the worst of the worst questions we get every day, many of them are being asked by people who have worked around the question ban in one way or another. When I'm regularly dealing with people who are on their fifth to seventh question-banned account, that's an awful lot of bad questions one person has been responsible for. Question-ban avoidance is also one of the primary drivers of sock puppet upvoting and coordinated voting rings.

Your proposed reputation cost system would only impact those who asked more than their three "free" questions, yet were not question-banned and who didn't earn enough reputation to keep "paying" for additional questions. I'm thinking that's not a very large portion of the really bad questions we get every day. Also, it would add an incentive to get voting rings or sock puppets to inflate your reputation so that you could keep asking. As I indicated, question-ban-related vote fraud is a real problem right now, and I see this making it worse. That distorts the voting on bad content, pushing it ahead of the good.

Cracking down on question ban recidivism (both by more effective prevention of new account creation and by helping to suss out vote fraud around it) will in my opinion have a significant impact on the volume of bad questions being asked. [I hear there is work being done on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/135615), and I am eagerly anticipating that coming online.

To aid this, we need to be able to identify and deal with bad questions earlier. The weighting for the close votes queue [has shifted to newer posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions), which is leading to more questions being closed sooner rather than later. Perhaps better heuristics for placing new questions in the Low Quality Posts review queue could also help pick these out earlier. There have to be other ways of having the system identify problematic posts. Improvements here would assist with a reinforced question-asking ban to identify and throttle the worst askers.

Comment: Fifth to seventh q-banned account?! Are you serious? /me screams in terror

Comment: Five to seven q-banned accounts? Holy sh*t. Can we please have a Badge for this? And while we're at it, a badge for *mindless robo-reviewer*, as well ? This would give everyone a chance to get some badges before JonSkeet grabs them all :-)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - A comment left by one such user this morning: "downvote all you want I will just create more and more new accounts and my questions will continued be answered. Worked out for me so far :D."

Comment: Thank you for writing such a clear and authoritative answer. This answer contains a lot of elements I did not think of. After reading this, I realized my proposal would 1. mostly only hinder people who already behave perfectly fine, 2. not stop people from starting new accounts for getting 'free' questions and 3. maybe even cause (more) vote fraud. So a way too naive solution to a complex problem I would say now.

Comment: In line with my comments on the question-ban recidivism, this is worth a read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/19679

Comment: Was about to post a contradicting answer, but after reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253168/low-rep-users-should-not-be-able-to-ask-questions/253179#253179 I realized you're right. It's a complicated economics question. But we need *some* barrier. Could you make them sit through a training on how to write better questions? Introduce a delay for all new accounts, [like this answer suggests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256304/541136)? You need to impose *some* cost on bad questioners. And I think bad questioners *can* be rehabilitated. And that might be good?

Comment: @AaronHall - It's a great question to contemplate. I don't know how we stop the "do my work for me"-style abusive askers while still letting good new people get a start here. The low-hanging fruit is to improve our means of keeping out those who have repeatedly demonstrated they will not play well within the system (repeat question-ban evaders), because it's pretty easy to work around safeguards right now. That by itself will stop a ton of bad questions (a single one of these bad users can dump dozens to hundreds of bad questions on the site) without harming anyone else.

Comment: If there isn't a marginal cost to SO for a new account, then tell visitors to create an anonymous account well in advance (24 hours?) Create a verification system for instant access? SO is fairly mature, so this may not be for other SE sites, but especially at this point, do we really want to be sucking in every possible question?

Answer (score 3):

I understand there are a bunch of bad questions being posted daily.

However, wouldn't your suggestion also reduce the amount of new users? I believe you can be a new user with little programming knowledge and still post quality questions. Yet, could a new user post quality answers to get those required 10 points, to post questions, if they are completely new to programming? It would be hard if you are truly starting out.

I also agree with Plutonix, a lot of people post their questions, some are crap and some are actually decent, but they don't even bother to return to the site. So three free questions might not solve anything.

I mention this because there might be a danger to the site losing a lot of traffic if too strict of rules for participating are implemented -- that is what I am most concern for. I have seen a lot of communities perish because they only relied on old members/traffic. I am all for reducing bad posts, but it can't be too drastic.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but in my opinion, StackOverflow (and the experts able to give *brilliant* answers -who are still around-) is a `valuable` resource (especially for those on a learning curve). This is why I think it's still  pretty reasonable to impose a tiny challenge for someone who wishes to address this community (for free, after all).

Comment: I think the point is the site has *too much* traffic--too much noise.  Of course this might reduce traffic, that's the point (;

Comment: I have seen a lot of communities perish because they only relied on old members/traffic. I am all for reducing bad posts, but it can't be too drastic.

Comment: Agreed.  And at the same time, it's really hard to be thorough when the entire front page changes between question views.

Comment: I've said it before and I'll keep saying it: Stack Overflow isn't where you go to learn how to program. Further, _everyone_, beginners to Guido, needs to be able to formulate a good question about a specific problem whose domain she understands in order to be welcome here. "New to SO", "new to programming", and "bad at asking questions" are all independent variables, and the only one we care about is the third.

Comment: @joshcaswell      I never said there was a relation between being new and asking poor questions. "Stack Overflow isn't where you go to learn how to program." I don't know about you but I've learned a thing or two about programming from some quality posts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely opposed to this idea, at least without enough complexity to the logic to make it unwieldy in practice. I personally don't ask very many questions, and [the ones I do ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526643/how-do-i-delay-evaluation-of-a-spring-conditional-configuration-annotation) tend to be arcane enough that they get very few views, much less upvotes, even when they're researched, specific, and objective.

Letting bad questions get buried in downvotes is penalty enough.

Comment: I think the argument is that your arcane questions don't get very many views because they're lost amid the sea of useless questions so it's really a crap shoot if the stars align and someone else with knowledge of your arcane situation even finds your question in the first place.

Comment: @dcow I seriously doubt that that explains much of it. My questions are extremely specific, and the self-described question-reading habits of most answerers don't include them. They tend to get views and responses from individuals with a deep expertise in the specific field (e.g., the Spring annotation-configuration parsing lifecycle), but those pools are very small.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be problematic for you if you don't ask a lot of questions. A user like you has lots of rep from answering. You personally even have enough upvotes on _one_ of your questions to cover what you've asked (at 10 rep per ask).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm a believer in the mental-friction theory of costs. Adopting the proposal would penalize *only* individuals who have already made some sort of contribution that got their rep above 1 in the first place.

Comment: It's true that 10 points of rep is more signficant when you're a new user, and any kind of sliding scale for the cost would quickly become the complex logic you mention...

Answer (score -4):

I share the concern that adding a barrier to entry could potentially shake off more people than desired.  Personally, I don't think imposing a small cost would be terrible, but you'd need to find the right cost that balances the signal/noise ratio as you want.  If you can do this without losing overall traffic, that's even better.  But, I have another idea.

What about a system that **pins** good questions longer?  So, say you ask a question and it gets an upvote.  Then, perhaps all questions with an upvote will appear above questions with no votes for a fixed amount of time.  If a question gets an accepted answer maybe it falls off the list or moves to a new one.  Basically, imagine the "front page" of SO functioning a little more like Reddit.  *(From what I understand questions do get bumped when they undergo a meaningful action, but bumped may not be enough.)*

This a few advantages:

1. It rewards good questions rather than punishing bad ones.
2. It gives more attention to meaningful and interesting questions and makes them easier to return to since, supposedly, they should be the community's focus.
3. It has much less of a threat of reducing overall site traffic while at the same time potentially improving the experience for all new users.

Win-win?

Comment: This doesn't really relate to the proposal here; I'm not even sure it's talking about the same problem. Please put your proposal into its own question, and use your answer here for responding directly to this one.

Comment: You're right, it's more of a reply to another answer.  But, I think it's related in that it's an alternate way to address the issue of common questions being overlooked because there is a large influx of new questions.