# Unable to flag answers as 'very low quality'

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, flags, low-quality-posts

I have noticed a number of poor link-only answers in the last few days, however when I went to flag one as 'very low quality' (a couple of days ago) the option was not there. Only the 'not an answer'/'in need of moderation intervention'/etc were available.

This happened again today. Both posts in question had a score of 0, and were link-only answers.

[image: No VLQ]

Comment: It's still there. But the VLQ flag option is hidden, if the post has a positive score.

Comment: Does 0 count as positive?

Comment: No, with 0 you should be able to flag it.

Comment: And yet I couldn't!

Comment: @RachelGallen It needed to have had a non-positive score at the time you loaded the page, not at the instant you click the flag button.

Comment: @Servy i chronically reload the page (to see new answers/questions etc..) it was still 0, and it wasn't a once-off occurence

Comment: @Glorfindel i have 1001 helpful flags - am i cut off after 1000?

Comment: No, and even reaching your daily # of flags would at least still show a message why you can't flag anymore.

Comment: @RobertLongson the bug seems to only occur on answers, as indicated by title

Comment: @RobertLongson when i went to flag this question i got should be closed/ a duplicate/ in need of moderator intervention

Comment: @RobertLongson flaggable, yes. Note that this happened on Stack overflow, it wasn't on meta

Comment: So on [this answer for instance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37937975/1038015) to pick one at random there's no VLQ option but all other usual options are present

Comment: @RobertLongson same for all, and note other bug while you're at it

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different sites: meta.stackexchange (where your rep is 130) and meta.stackoverflow (this site) where your rep is synced with the main SO site every 15 minutes.

Comment: If you [look at your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1675954/rachel-gallen?tab=topactivity) and click on the helpful flags text are there any messages? Have you had flags declined in the last 10 days?

Comment: @RobertLongson i only have 25 declined flags, total out of 1062, 31 disputed. the 25th declined one was on June 6th. There are no messages.

Comment: @hichris123 it is not a duplicate, as the other question refers to a question  with a positive score.

Comment: I must say I'm confused then. You should be able to flag any zero-scored answer as VLQ. Can you link to an example of this?

Comment: @hichris123 look at above screenshot. This is what comes up, whichever I click on. It's the same across the board

Comment: So for any answer you click 'flag' on, this is what you see? I'm inclined to think this is something on your computer/network's side -- I see VLQ on [Robert's linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937637/how-to-rotate-a-svg-hexagonal-shape/37937975#37937975).

Comment: @hichris123 obviously this option was available before a couple of days ago, otherwise I wouldn't have over 1000 helpful flags. Currently that is the case. Btw, I'm eating dinner so excuse if I don't Rsvp to next comment immediately!

Comment: We seem to be getting away from the can't flag low quality issue.

Comment: It seems that the VLQ option is gone for answers older than 7 days.

Comment: @pang pls add as an answer, and if possible, explain why?

Comment: Re your rep. Here on Meta Stack **Overflow** your rep is the same as on Stack Overflow (12.4k). It's your Meta Stack **Exchange** rep that's 130. Double check which site you're on when you see the different scores.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[bluefeet's been doing a bit of analysis and soul-searching with regard to the Very Low Quality flag lately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage):

> When flagging questions as VLQ, we're inadvertently sending too much noise to the moderators to handle.

...

> **Problem 1:** Currently, when a question is older than 7 days and it receives a VLQ flag it bypasses Triage and goes directly to the moderators.

There are a few ways we could've solved this particular problem, but the truth is that very few VLQ flags ever get raised on posts over 7 days old... Heck, 87% of all VLQ flags are raised on questions less than *one* day old. The vast, vast majority of the worst cruft gets cleaned up quickly...

...and when it doesn't, there's often something else going on:

- **Spelling or grammar problems** aren't great, but a question that's been sitting around, answered, *for months or years*, is probably good enough to be understood. Editing to fix the problems or simply downvoting will suffice.
- Extremely short or **link-only answers** are often of extremely poor quality, but those that've survived for years are usually at least understandable; their greatest flaws tend to be in not actually answering the question, for which there exists another flag (one used far, far more often already).
- And then there are the thousands of terrible questions with no answers that **no one has ever bothered to look at**. Most of these will be automatically deleted sooner or later anyway; a flag doesn't really help much. A downvote will speed things along a bit though.

So as of about 24 hours ago, the VLQ flag is no longer available on posts older than 7 days (the precise value may change, but 7 seems reasonable). We'll be monitoring flags (especially NAA and "Other") to ensure this doesn't cause problems; feel free to voice any concerns here on meta as well.

Kudos to [Michael Stum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum) for implementing this change - also, please join me in welcoming him to the core development team!

Comment: does this also impact [low-quality auto-flagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150253/165773)? Per my observations [downvotes cast on marginal quality answers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31260) tended to push these to LQ queue, would this still be the case for votes cast on answers older than 7 days?

Comment: I'm going from memory here, but iirc that works based on a hidden quality score coupled with the public post score, @gnat - so, unaffected.

Comment: understood, thanks. Basically, the intent was to prevent only manual VLQ flagging, right?

Comment: To be clear, does this render obsolete the [merging of NAA and VLQ flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one)? Is the end-goal to remove completely the VLQ flag for both Q + A?

Comment: I'd say no @Tunaki, we haven't made any decisions on that.  The purpose of this change was to minimize noise going to the mods because of the way the VLQ flag and Triage worked or didn't work depending on your perspective.

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution have been to send these older VLQ flags to the queue, rather than directly to mods?  The VLQ queue seems to be well under control.

Comment: @WarrenDew The VLQ queue doesn't really work for questions that's what the Close Queue and Triage are for.

Comment: @bluefeet Looking at the length of the queues, I'd say it's the close queue that doesn't work, not the VLQ queue.  VLQ is for things that are unintelligible, spam, or not even answers/questions, so it's easier to evaluate and easier to clear.

Comment: @WarrenDew you look at it under wrong angle. Size doesn't matter much here. Close queue is less troublesome because it doesn't overload moderators: everything is intended to be handled by 3K users, and its size is controlled by config settings that age questions out of it automagically. Add that close votes and flags expire and recast and this makes it even smoother. LQ queue is different in that stuff that isn't quickly handled by reviewers gets to diamond mods (and it tends to be quite cumbersome to handle)

Comment: Hey that is great welcome @MichaelStum !

Comment: @Jeff Thanks! Honored to be here

Comment: "Heck, 87% of all VLQ flags are raised on questions less than one day old." Did you excluded the auto flags and the H&I queue flags?

Comment: I excluded auto-flags, @Braiam (auto-LQ flags aren't raised on Stack Overflow at all). VLQ flags raised in the H&I queue behave identically to VLQ flags raised everywhere else - in theory, you could circumvent this restriction by using the option in the H&I queue, but in practice questions that old should never be *in* the H&I queue.

Comment: Does the analysis change here on sites that don't even have triage, or don't have nearly as many constantly-active high-rep users monitoring for LQ stuff? We already have users on SF&F trying to flag things that are too old and it's only been 2 weeks...

Comment: @bluefeet, I didn't fully understand your response to Warren Dew.  Wouldn't a better solution have been to send older VLQ flags *on answers* to the queue, rather than directly to mods?  (And disable VLQ flags on older *questions*.)  One of the benefits of the VLQ flag is that it is the only supported way to coordinate a group of 3 20K users to vote to delete a crummy answer.  It seems like it'd be useful to be able to flag an older answer as VLQ and send it to a queue where 20K users can vote to delete.  This seems to serve the goal of avoiding flooding mods with these flags.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer.  You say this change was documented in bluefeet's post.  However, bluefeet's post only talks about disabling VLQ flags on older *questions*.  However, as the question points out, apparently VLQ flags have been disabled on older *answers*, too.  I'm not seeing that described anywhere in bluefeet's post, and I'm not seeing it justified.  Is there a misunderstanding here about the distinction between VLQ flags on questions vs VLQ flags on answers, or a misunderstanding lumping the two into a single category?

Comment: *"Heck, 87% of all VLQ flags are raised on questions less than one day old."* - does this question only consider VLQ flags on *questions*?  Or is it also including VLQ flags on answers, and using the age of the question that the answer is responding to as the filtering condition?

Comment: @D.W. As of right now the availability of the VLQ for both questions and answers is tied together which means that if either a question or answer are older than 7 days the flag is not available.  Initially, yes I specifically looked at questions but the final implementation has changed for both types of posts.  If we determine there is a need, then we can adjust as needed.

Comment: So just to clarify, if an answer is old it can't be low quality? What should people be flagging or doing with answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15783060/3509591) ?

Comment: The flag you raised was fine, @Zze - it explained a problem that wouldn't have been obvious from a cursory examination of the post. Strictly-speaking, it wasn't a link-*only* answer - there was the barest amount of auxiliary information accompanying the link. However, it's hard to argue that the answer still served a purpose with the link broken, and so removing it provides a useful service to future readers.