# Why do I get different flag options for different questions?

Tags: support, flags

For some questions, I get the following 3 flagging options:

[image]

For some other, I get more:

[image]

In either case, I won't get all the options in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Why is it different from question to question?

And why can't I see all the options in the dialog?

Comment: Is the question already closed, or deleted?

Comment: Well if a question is closed it does not make sense to give you that option since it is moot.  Can you show 2 questions that give you this behavior?

Comment: The first screenshot was from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060979/python-machine-learning). The second was from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel-error-apache-shutdown-unexpect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that [Your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060979/python-machine-learning) is closed while [the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel-error-apache-shutdown-unexpect) is open.  Since the first question is closed there is no reason to give you the duplicate close or should be closed reasons as the question is already closed.  You cannot close a closed question.

All the other flags remain the same as those are still valid options for both questions.  You will also notice that the Very Low Quality flag will come and go as it is based on the votes on the question or votes and age of the answer.  For more on the behavior of VLQ flags see: [Unable to flag as 'very-low-quality' (for answers)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326585/unable-to-flag-as-very-low-quality-for-answers)

Comment: That explains it: It wasn't yet closed as I came there, I guess I'd need to refresh screen before flagging :) Thanks for the explanation on VLQ too, that was my other question, indeed!

Comment: @Luis No problem.  I figured That would also come up.

Answer (score 2):

The missing options refer to a state in which the question should be closed.  Since the question you refer to is closed as a duplicate, flagging it for closure is useless since the system already considers it closed.