# What to do with a link only answer that was correct, but now links to malicious site

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, external-links

I've found an unusual case.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295395/minify-merge-javascript-minify-css-on-visual-studio-build) has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297575/852806), marked as correct with **21** upvotes. The user has a good rep and checks out as a good SO user.

When I click on the link, I get a malicious content warning in Firefox/Chrome.

[image: Link attempt in chrome]

I could edit the answer, but without the link, the answer doesn't make sense.

[image]

What is the correct course of action? Should it be marked in need of Moderator intervention? That would leave the question without an answer and a big reputation drop for the user.

Comment: Flag it anyway - link only answers aren't very useful (as this question shows)

Comment: While flagging, and to prevent this malware from propagating, you may also want to replace the link with a [Wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/) one.

Comment: @Kyll - Darn it. That is what i should have done. Would have been better for the honest user and the community.

Comment: This is so totally excactly why link-only answers are frowned upon. Everyone should read this question. :)

Comment: The page was still available on [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fencosia.com%2F2009%2F05%2F20%2Fautomatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio%2F), so I made [a PDF of it](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=90288494765008391953&t=9028849476500839195377802). Unfortunately, there's no good/permanent way to host PDFs on the Internet, but if someone wants a bunch of rep, they could distill the contents of this blog post into an answer. It is always better *not to lose the information* than to get your delete jollies.

Comment: So you put on hold a question dating from '09?

Comment: @Cody This is what I was going to suggest myself. Normally flagging and deleting is the way to go but with something with so many upvotes, it would be worth it to clean it up using the cached info.

Comment: @Kyll Iv replaced it.

Comment: This malware alert does not mean there is a malware... On official websites and forums, this can show up. It simply means that the browser detected a potential risk, nothing more. It does not mean there is a problem with the web page. Also, the word `programs` is misspelled as `programmes`, is it really an official warning?

Comment: @Kyll unless they nuke it with a `robots.txt`... *[I'm with Jeff on this one](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/748074095481335808)*

Comment: @david Probably a British-localized version of the message. Those folks on the other side of the pond have their funny little spellings. What do they think, they invented the language? Indeed, the message just signifies the potential, but I don't think anyone will be volunteering to be a guinea pig.

Comment: @CodyGray we do indeed have funny spellings, but in British English, program is used for computer programs. Programme is for all other uses, though I feel it's getting less popular.

Comment: We can now delete-vote the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One of the proposed comments in the VLQ Review Queue is the "link-only answer":

> “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   **Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes**.”

It should definitely be flagged, regardless of the upvotes it has.

Comment: Have flagged. Seems a shame for the person who's answered it. Will mark this as the answer when SO allows me.

Comment: I'm very tempted to remove the link altogether.

Comment: (In fact, I did). Also: _deleted by Jon Clements♦ 24 secs ago_

Comment: "link-only answer" isn't a flag option. It is one of the proposed canned comments in the VLQ Review Queue. (_in b4 link-onlys should be flagged as VLQ or NAA_)

Comment: @Tunaki It's obvious OP should flag as VLQ. I gave that as a justification for flagging it.

Comment: Moderators are hesitant to remove link-only answers, so in my opinion a custom flag is warranted in this situation so you can give the moderator reviewing your flag a bit more info about *why* the answer should be removed. Otherwise if you simply flag NAA on a link-only accepted answer, your flag will be declined.

Comment: We can now delete-vote the question.

Answer (score 15):

When NAA flags fail, I've had success with custom mod flags using the following message/template:

> This answer is a link only answer which has become the victim of link rot. 20k+ users cannot vote to delete this answer because of its positive score.

This has worked on at least 2 accepted link-only answers for me recently.  The key here is to explicitly explain why this post requires moderator intervention.  Without context, a mod might decline a NAA or less-descriptive flag.

Comment: It's not "NAA" because it's an answer. You should only use "NAA" when the post isn't anything remotely close to an answer, like "Thanks, that helped" or "But what about my edge case?". Downvote low quality answers (such as those with only a link) or use custom mod flags in other scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

A few weeks ago, I would have advised to flag the answer as Low Quality - however, that is [not possible anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326585/unable-to-flag-as-very-low-quality-for-answers/326635#326635), because the post is more than 7 days old. Flagging as 'Not an answer' won't help - link-only answer *are* answers, albeit bad ones (compared to *current* standards - back in 2009, when the question was asked, the policies were different). A moderator flag would be justified in this case, but **only** because the link got infected.

However, the whole question is bad - it is a typical case of a tool/library recommendation and it should be closed as such (which just happened).

Comment: We [can't delete-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) that question. It's got too many upvotes, and a accepted answer.

Comment: Best case: a mod gets rid of the question altogether.

Comment: You couldn't have flagged it as VLQ before the change anyway.  You can only cast the flag on answers that aren't accepted and have a negative score

Comment: @Cerbrus actually you *can*. It will take you 10 10kersr.

Comment: @Braiam: I have over 33k rep and I can't delete-vote that.

Comment: @Cerbrus check again in 30 hours. 1100 UTC of tomorrow.

Comment: We're now able to cast delete-votes on the question, since I re-opened a question marked as dupe of this one. That [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549427/in-visual-studio-2013-how-do-i-minify-javascript-and-css-in-the-post-build-step) has better answers, and is of better overall quality.