# Previously safe link, now potentially malicious

Tags: discussion, external-links

I've previously answered questions dealing with the FluentSecurity project for .NET. Unfortunately, it appears the official documentation URL is parked (and has been for a while now), and (from my very recent experience) now redirects a potentially malicious website. What is the best method of handling this?

The project itself still seems fine - the [Github project](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity) doesn't seem to be affected (other than linking to the possibly problematic URL), nor does the NuGet package, and maybe the redirect I experienced was more of a prank site than a real threat, but I don't have the requisite skillset to prove it one way or the other.

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326988/what-to-do-with-a-link-only-answer-that-was-correct-but-now-links-to-malicious) previous Q&A on Meta - should I just flag one (or all) open question(s) that link to the docs site? There seems to be a mix of "real" answers and link-only answers, so the accepted answer in the linked question isn't 100% applicable.

Comment: It appears this domain name and site is still owned by the same person: https://whois.domaintools.com/fluentsecurity.net Most-likely, their website has been compromised. In theory, this should be a temporary issue, assuming somebody does something about it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I've actually had a convo with the project owner - he knows it's parked. He's apparently in talks to have a company take over the project, although he didn't say when or who.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting their hosting provider then. There is no excuse for their inaction against this abuse. Their hosting provider will hopefully take it offline.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Well, the project owner is/was an active SO user, so if nothing else I hope this makes him aware that there *could* be a problem. I just don't know for certain, but I also can't justify not doing anything - hence this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you discover a malicious link that goes directly out from Stack Overflow then it needs to be removed.

It really depends on how many of these links there are. You can search for them yourself and if there are only a handful or dozen then manually editing them out should be fine.

If there are dozens or hundreds of occurrences of a malicious link then that will probably require a moderator's attention in order to involve a dev to wipe it out. Either use the contact us form at the bottom of every page, or flag one of the posts that contains that link and explain the exact situation (optionally also linking to this meta question for extra context).

If the link is not malicious, or if the link goes to a page which is not malicious but still contains malicious links, then that is borderline gray area, and to be honest users should always navigate with caution.

Comment: The site in question hijacked my browser, and wanted me to call a phone number to remove it - again, I don't have the skill set to know if it was truly compromising the machine I was using. I shut the machine down immediately, assuming it could leak into my network if it was, in fact, ransomware. At the moment, there are 33 questions, so I *could* just sanitize those and call it good.

Comment: @TiesonT. - And the link is straight to that site? I hate to ask if it is reproducible, but assuming it happens for every navigation that should definitely be removed. I don't think there would be any objections to you manually fixing the 33 questions provided that isn't too much of a burden on you.

Comment: The URL resolves to a blank page, and then immediately bounces through a few redirects - I haven't tried it again, as I have a limited supply of computers I can risk infection with. The URL has been parked for a while, so even if this is a temporary / one time problem, the links are invalid anyway, so perhaps it's worth just removing the links anyway. There's no Wayback Machine cache for the site, unfortunately, so that's not an option.

Comment: Also, I have no problem editing those questions. I just hate bouncing them all to the front page for no other reason...

Comment: @TiesonT. Sounds like the website could have been compromised by a hacker. Do you have one such answer you could link us to?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I've started editing them out, but here's one that I haven't edited yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599486/does-one-still-require-an-ioc-to-use-fluent-security

Comment: Okay, it looks like most of the links can be repointed at the Github project, so I'm just going to do that and call it good. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @TiesonT., an alternative link target to use when changing the links would be an archive of the link originally used. [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333503/3773011) has some bookmarklets which may help in finding appropriate archives. However, from what you have described, you may want to search for the archives directly rather than clicking through the link and then using those bookmarklets. Using an archive link may better preserve the original intent of the OP for each post. It is something you would need to judge on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Makyen There **aren't** any archives of the website, since the robots.txt told the Internet Archive not to archive the site. I suppose I could try digging for other archives, but since the majority of the links could be repointed at the wiki on the Github project, that is what I did.