# How to report low quality answers that are not only link only but DEAD link only?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

What is the correct way to report [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289871/177800) is useless garbage now to get it into a queue to be deleted?

There is no available "low quality" choice anymore? And it will get declined, rightly so as `NAA` and it is not worth flagging to get a mod involved?

**Outside resorting to a chat room how to get this reported?**

[image]

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not not an answer, as the question says.  It provides an answer to the question.

Comment: `NAA` will just get `declined` and one step closer to getting you flag banned because pretty much anything other than [a cat walking across the keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cat+walking+on+keyboard) qualifies as *an attempt to answer*, and even then you can argue the cat intended to answer, a dog probably not.

Comment: Yeah. I don't actually see the issue here. It may not be the most awesome answer in the world, but it checks all the boxes. There's actually nothing technically wrong with it. If it's not helpful or such, then that's solved by downvoting, which it looks like others are already doing.

Comment: The answer is fundamentally a link only answer and **the link is dead**, it is useless noise.

Comment: It is not a link only answer though. It's a link, plus some sample code. That's enough to take it out of "link only" status.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The answer is fundamentally suggesting a product and demonstrating how to use it.  That's not a link only answer.  The link could be deleted and it would still be an answer.  The link is in no way essential to the answer at all.  The problem with the answer is that what it is suggesting be used (apparently) doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: If you're so concerned about the dead link, you can replace it. [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130402202109/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+SOAP) to the rescue.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: The SO unofficially official stance is to err on the side of keeping content. If there's any question about whether it might actually be worth keeping, it's worth keeping.

Comment: Relevant, for the inability for flag as VLQ: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326585/unable-to-flag-as-very-low-quality-for-answers

Comment: There is no question that this particular case is irrelevant and needs to be removed, it was wrong/bad information when it was posted and the link presumably worked, it is even more so crap now that the link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

When you find an answer that is incorrect, or otherwise unhelpful (in this case, it sounds like the relevant feature has been depreciated from the product) then the appropriate course of action is to downvote and optionally comment explaining why the answer isn't helpful (someone has already done so here, but you may be able to expand on it as the last comment was from 2013).