# Photo of sourcecode as an answer

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I just stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066169/3214843) which is a series of photos (yes, photos - not even screenshots). If it was a question I would without a second thought vote to close it, but in this case it is an upvoted and accepted answer and none of the available flags apply.

What to do in such a case?
Have any of you encountered something like this before?

[image: The answer in case]

Comment: Flag it as "NAA", I believe?

Comment: @yivi That was my first thought, but while the medium he chose to do so is objectively bad, it is technically an answer. I usually only use NAA when people write comments as answers (lack of reputation), ask questions like *"Hav u solvd dis?"* or similar things.

Comment: Yes. In questions is reason for closure, but you are right that it may not be the same for answers.

Comment: Do you happen to volunteer to transcribe the thing to text? I don't.

Comment: Personally, I'd treat it as an answer in a different language. NAA or VLQ. But I've been wrong about this before.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Hell no! ^^

Comment: I like how those are not even screenshots, but actual photos... :P

Comment: Kids these days. "It's easier to take a pic and upload it than to select text, copy, go to website, paste". In my days we entered programs in hex/patched software on a floppy disk with a magnetized needle/debugged Stonehenge by chiseling off corners with our teeth (pick any one).

Comment: *it is technically an answer* If you can't read the images then all the post says is "I think you can do as follow", which isn't an answer.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Intriguing way of answering. The crowd that complains about how programmers these days just copy and paste code from Stack Overflow will surely approve of this answerer's dutiful attempt to see off such malfeasance and thereby improve programming standards!

Comment: I remember seeing [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z0pn.jpg) in a question. Seriously, whiteout‽

Comment: Not just images of code when it's far easier to paste text into the answer, but the images are low quality and all taken at jaunty angles. If I didn't know better, I would assume we were being trolled!

Comment: Am I alone in thinking that a comment telling the user to post their answer as formatted text would have been sufficient? This was their first ever answer I think, and they have gone on to post correctly formatted answers. Downvoting and deleting answers from new users who are providing potentially useful content (just in the wrong form) seems unnecessary to me, such answers are an eye sore but not that harmful IMO

Comment: What I would like to know most of all is not how to flag this answer, but what this person's thought process was when they were uploading photos of source code as an answer.

Comment: @Chris_Rands It's only sufficient sometimes. Other times the user will reply with something like, "Thanks, I'll do that next time". And these posts do cause harm in that it hides information from anyone who can't read the image, whether it's do to poor image quality or not being able to see it at all.

Comment: The user is not the point on this website, @Chris_Rands. Sure, comment to explain how the  post  could be improved, but if it's a bad post, then **also downvote**.

Comment: So anybody could technically give a right answer by writing the code by hand, then upload it as a photo. Sounds fun to me. But then what? Would we have to OCR the image? It can be done with Adobe PDF reader. Are browsers technically impaired in this respect?

Comment: These are rare. Take a photo of them. Also, I would downvote because I don't know what these pictures are about. Would ask to take a screenshot (with a link to a tutorial on how to make one), or at very least, ask nicely to take another round of photoshoot.

Comment: Is there a term for taking a photo to act as a screenshot? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421939/term-for-taking-a-screenshot-using-a-camera

Comment: @JF If we don't all keep using Liquid Paper, Mike Nesmith will have to reunite the Monkees.

Comment: Could it be the user is on the app, or using the site via phone? Typing an answer on a phone is surely going to be tricky, so this is the only way to help.

Comment: Uh, **there's a computer right in front of them**, @RichardLeMesurier. And if they can't use that for some reason, they should just wait until they _can_ post a proper answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that doesn't always mean they are logged in on that machine, nor that they have outside internet access with that machine. I just think that sometimes an imperfect answer is better than none, however I realise (from the votes here) that I'm in the minority and the vibe here is that if it ain't perfect keep it off our site. I mean if the person didn't think they were adding value, do you think they were just trolling us?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- **Downvote** - because it's not a useful answer.
  Downvoting is the primary method of quality control we have. If you find an answer like this that isn't useful or is low quality, downvote it to allow better answers a chance to appear above it. Downvoting also potentially brings the post to a negative score, which opens up the VLQ flag option. Speaking of which...
- **Flag** as VLQ.
  Flagging as Very Low Quality sends the post to the Low Quality Posts review queue, where a wider scope of the community will see it and be able to vote on whether we should keep it or not. (You will only be able to flag as VLQ if the answer is negatively scored and less than a week old, unfortunately, so the option may not be available.)
- **Comment** if you feel like it.
  The effectiveness of a comment is something you'll have to judge for yourself - whether the post is recent, whether the author is likely to respond constructively, etc. If you think it's worth it, you can leave a comment asking the author to edit their post to include the code as text and potentially even a bit of explanation.

---

Alternatively, if you're feeling nice, you can **edit** to fix it yourself.
  You can also fix up the answer yourself - transcribe the code into text and post that; try to work out how it works and how it differs from the question and what fixes the problem the asker was having. That'll take a while to do, but ultimately is the best way to improve the quality of the Q&A.

Comment: I agree with the downvote. While it may have been useful to the OP, it certainly isn't to anyone else with the same problem. VLQ would be pretty on point, but I don't see that as an option.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Aye, the post needs to be negatively (or maybe zero as well) scored to show VLQ as a flag option. That's part of the purpose of downvoting, to try to open that option up.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Guess I'll stick around that answer until that happens.

Comment: Looks like the meta effect has done its usual, and it's now at -4.

Comment: It's currently at -4, but the VLQ option doesn't show... Maybe because it is an accepted answer?

Comment: @yivi It's probably not instant

Comment: [Unable to flag as very low quality for answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326585) - One of the many arcane rules for the flag is that it isn't an option on posts more than a week old. @ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: *"the VLQ flag is no longer available on posts older than 7 days (the precise value may change, but 7 seems reasonable)"*

Comment: Huh. I had a feeling there was something else I was missing, but I wasn't sure what. Thanks for the find, @Josh.

Comment: Looking at the user's other posts tends to be a good idea, easy to see that he did figure out how to do it correctly later this month.  So a comment could easily have worked.

Comment: I would have flagged as Not An Answer. If you have a proxy that blocks images (as I do), the only text is "I think you Can do it as follow" which is obviously not an answer

Comment: +1 But it does not feel right though.. the quality of the answer isn't bad per se because we can not copy paste it easily enough.

Comment: The quality of the answer is definitely bad, @Code4R7. It's not about ease of copy-pasting, it's that we as a community expect contributors to have enough respect for their own work and others' time to format their contributions well.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If you have a proxy that removes Stack Overflow answers then they all appear blank, that doesn't mean that if I had such a proxy I'd be correct in flagging them all NAA.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I see. Does the same apply to answers that are less readable (or unreadable in some text-based browsers) like [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default#answer-6163129) for example because the text is upside down? And what if we use a browser that *can* copy paste from an image using OCR?

Comment: @Code4R7 With really popular answers like that one, I'd tend to stay away from editing them too much, personally. They managed to get the votes looking like that, so it's probably okay.