# Adding a few words to the "debugging help" close reason would go a long way

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Today, the close reason reads similar to this:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

This isn't exactly clear because people often believe that including a picture in the question satisfies the "shortest code necessary" requirement.

Can we simply add these words?  (Emphasis mine)

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary **(not a picture or video of your code)** to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to
>   create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: How do I flex my diamond?

Comment: This might cause users to ask how to post videos of their code ;) How about "... shortest code in text format necessary to reproduce..."?

Comment: @honk:  I will add that in while I roll my eyes...Geez.  Who would dare post a video of their code and have the question survive for more than an hour?

Comment: @BoltClock:  I'm confused and afraid.  What are you on about? :)

Comment: @Makoto: Apparently mods can edit close reasons according to their whims. (I wasn't about to hammer your question, in case it came off that way...)

Comment: Ah.  Fair enough.  I knew that diamond moderators had the ability to do that though, which is kinda why I posted this.  Hopefully we can get some consensus around this and then have that happen?

Comment: @BoltClock Specifically just the custom close reasons, but this is one of them, so yeah.  Can't just go around changing "unclear" though.

Comment: Related: [Modify the \[MCVE\] page to emphasize \[edit\]-ing question body](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373837/4642212).

Comment: @Makoto: Yeah, I made that comment because I realized I have no idea how to even use the thing.

Comment: @Makoto I don't know, closing a question within an hour just because they posted a video of their question doesn't sound very welcoming to new users. ;)

Comment: Or a link (unless accompanying text).

Comment: @BoltClock you don't want to flex it - diamond is notoriously brittle ;)

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: I thought so!

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364807/241211) is my favorite bad example.

Comment: Okay @BoltClock - I'm thinking that +24 is plenty of consensus on this one.  Want to "flex" your diamond then or give it a week?

Comment: I would second @honk's suggestion, may be something like ....shortest code necessary **(as a text only)** ... work !?

Comment: @BoltClock - Shameless promotion of [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376731/157247) below, though I tend to assume you're not going to rush off and do this willy-nilly. :-)

Comment: @honk - Added [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376731/157247) doing that.

Comment: @coder-croc - Added [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376731/157247) doing that. (Really wish multiple `@` notifications were a thing.)

Comment: Occasionally I come across questions that post screenshots of code, but from what I can see it's not a widespread issue. In my experience it goes one of two ways: a) the querent is asked to post code as text in a comment and amends their question either before it's closed, or b) the querent is asked to post code as text in a comment and never amends their question, even after it's closed. Hence I'm not sure adding this extra information to a close reason would be that helpful. Adding it to the new question wizard on the other hand might indeed be worthwhile (in case it's not there already).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers What?! It's widespread like a plague, I'd say we get at least 10 questions like that every day. And it is only getting more common.

Comment: How about we simply make it a privilege to post questions containing pictures? 300 rep or so? This would block the vast majority of all "pictures of code" questions. At the expense of those who have valid reasons to post pictures, but they seem to be a small minority compared to the screenshot-of-code kids.

Comment: @Lundin Wow. O_o In the tags I'm active in it's more like once every 10 weeks or so.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Seen it 4 times this week below the C tag alone, and then I haven't even been that active. It seems to be an issue mostly related to posters using IDEs like Visual Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: @Lundin - There already is a limit to posting inline images, but people still include their code screenshots as raw URLs instead. (Hmmm.... I [can't find that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) in the list of privileges. Maybe I just...assumed...they couldn't post images, when in fact they just hadn't figured out how? But I could have *sworn*...)

Comment: @Lundin - It's not my memory playing tricks, the info is just missing from the [remove new user restrictions page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) ([bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376733/update-help-center-privileges-remove-new-user-restrictions-to-note-inline-im)). I created a new account and tried to post an image via the image tool. It said I couldn't do that until 10 rep and that it had included a link instead. (10 is a lot lower than your suggested 300, of course.)

Comment: @BoltClock I know how to use it. I discovered it by accident. :)

Comment: ... nor _links_ to **videos** of _links_ that point to **images** of _code_ stored elsewhere ...  (just waiting to find one of those

Comment: Is there data on how frequently on hold/closed questions with pictures are currently salvaged by removing the pictures?

Comment: @JETM - I'd love to see that. Anecdotally, for me in the tags I frequent ([tag:javascript], [tag:html], [tag:css], [tag:java]) it's **very** hit-or-miss, and you can usually tell from the quality of the rest of the question whether it'll happen. (Generally well-written otherwise? Yes. Generally poor, vague, and clearly not even read-through before posting? No.)

Comment: @SouravGhosh:  I wonder what we've accomplished by closing this as a dupe.  I totally see that it *is*, but I wonder what closing it has actually benefitted...

Comment: Probably accomplished about the same as leaving it open would.

Comment: @KevinB:  I'd say less; we can't post any definite improvements *here* until it's reopened.

Comment: @BoltClock:  So where are we at with "consensus" on this matter then?

Comment: @Makoto: I'm only getting around to it now because reasons, but now I've hit another roadblock: the current close reason is already at the very edge of a bloody **character limit**. Any attempt to incorporate this into the existing reason will have to sacrifice an entire other sentence. Currently considering axing the "clear problem statement" bit since, while important, it appears quite tangential to the essence of the reason.

Comment: Uh, @BoltClock?  How about that text update? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very much like this addition. I would tweak it *slightly*:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (as **text**, not as a picture, video, or off-site link). Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

or

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Include code as **text**, not as a picture, video, or off-site link. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

("picture" could be "screenshot")

Comment: Isn't saying "Don't add a picture of your code" like "Do not think about a pink elephant"? As in: isn't it better to not mention pictures/videos at all, but simply stick with what they should do: post it in text? Reconsideration: when the 'evil' has already been done (there's a picture/video) it's presumably fine, but if there's no code (text, or otherwise) won't they then add it as a picture anyway, since you mentioned the word 'picture'?

Comment: @Adriaan don't jump out the window. Damn, will I be convicted for murdering you know? Why would people suddenly start doing things if you tell them not to? Reasonable people looking for help with their questions, anyways.

Comment: @DonQuiKong "reasonable people" <- there's your problem. If they'd be reasonable, they'd have taken the [tour] and read [ask], including [mcve] and the question wouldn't be put on hold in the first place.

Comment: @Adriaan - If it weren't for the fact that people do it routinely without the prompt, I'd agree. Sadly, though, they do, so addressing it is (to my mind) appropriate.

Comment: @Adriaan oh but not infroming yourself and deliberately doing what you're told not to do are two pairs of shoes.

Comment: I like the second version more. The less braces and brackets in text which is not code, the better IMO.

Comment: Some will say: _links are text though_  :) - or at least think it. And who reads all those text boxes anyway?

Comment: @PatrickArtner - **LOL** No one, as we know. :-)

Comment: @Gimby - My preference as well, for exactly that reason.

Comment: I'd add *or a link* as that's the other issue we face often

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Doh! Done. :-)

Comment: "Include code / **error messages** as **well formatted/indented** text". Pleeeeeeease! Or something like that.

Comment: @GhostCat:  Error messages not being exactly formatted is probably the least egregious thing to occur.  If the error message *is* text, at least it *can* be formatted by someone else later on...it's just a mistake to try and transcribe error messages or anything from an image since [it leads to copy errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375129/1079354).