# Update Help Center > Privileges > Remove New User Restrictions to note inline images

Tags: bug, help-center, privileges

There are two entries on the [list of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) enabled at rep >= 10:

- [Create Wiki Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)
- [Remove New User Restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)

The second one should be updated to say that users can post inline images (prior to 10 rep, you can't post inline images; if you try to use the editor tool to do it, it tells you about the restriction and includes the image as a link instead).

Perhaps add the boldfaced bullet point:

> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than eight hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile
> - contribute answers to protected questions
> - ask or answer questions too rapidly
> - **post inline images (they can only post the image's URL, it's not shown inline)**

(Or create a third page for it, but it's clearly a "new user restriction," so it fits with the second page.)

Comment: The part between the ( and ) seems to indicate to me they also cannot post image url's, maybe moving it to a separate bullet list would be better

Comment: @Ferrybig - It's not a separate bullet item, it's a clarification of the "post inline images" part. Apparently not a very clear clarification, so I've reworded. :-)

Comment: I totally agree