# Should I review questions with images of code as "looks ok" or "requires editing"?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, triage, images

Sometimes I run across questions with screenshots of a code segment instead of the actual code in a code block. Other than that, it's a good question. Pictures of code are not as helpful as code blocks, but I'm not sure if it's that big of a deal.

Should I review questions with screenshots of code as "Looks OK" or "Requires Editing"?

Comment: @gnat no. I'm asking how to review posts with code images, and that's about why code images are bad. I don't see how this is a dup.

Comment: Are you aware that "Requires Editing" [actually means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues) "Requires Editing **that anyone can provide** (not just the author)"? The system really doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Why would there be things that another user could do that the author can't, @yivi?

Comment: Parsing it that way makes the button useless. Show me an example of an edit that a reviewer could do that the author could not.

Comment: Rules lawyering is a lot of fun; I do it for a living. But unless I'm talking to my compiler, I prefer to consider the intent, and the effects of my action, when deciding how to proceed.

Comment: It's hard for me to answer those questions because I can't see the images.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You and yivi are violently agreeing with each other. Here's a tip to help you understand how you've misunderstood each other: what yivi means by the sentence *'I believe it means "anyone but the author"'* and what you think they mean by that sentence are drastically different.

Comment: While we're at it, let me plug my feature request to [Raise / Remove reputation limit for showing “Do not upload code screenshots” message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367875/raise-remove-reputation-limit-for-showing-do-not-upload-code-screenshots-mes). I hope the day will come when this issue starts to ebb away.

Comment: @coldspeed once again, that's about discouraging images of code, not how to review them.

Comment: If they are to be discouraged, then they should be reviewed accordingly

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### Neither of the options you are considering.

If there are pictures of code instead of code, the question should be **closed**.

The most appropriate reason would be:

[image: lacks MCVE close reason]

*"Requires editing"* is when someone other then the post author can edit the question into shape (not a case when the required action is transcribing code).

It is the post author's responsibility to post a complete question. If a third party transcribes the code (which is a very big ask), it would be very easy for the editor to introduce errors or changes that would invalidate the question, and very difficult for anyone else to verify if the edit was appropriate.

Choosing "requires editing" would be wrong. Please, be sure that you **only choose this option when the question is otherwise fine and should remain open as it is**, but still could use some polishing by third parties.

*"Looks OK"* when the question is not closable otherwise. As in, it's complete and answerable. "Code as an image" does not a good and complete question make. So this would also be a bad choice.

The option you should be looking for is **Unsalvageable**.

Comment: Couldn't someone other than the author convert the image to text?

Comment: No, it's the post author responsability to post a complete question. If a third party transcribes the code (which is a **very** big ask), it would be very easy for the editor to introduce errors or changes that would invalidate the question.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain:  Related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376604/1079354

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain:  Also (directly) related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375129/1079354

Comment: While I agree a question should be put on hold while in such a state, I definitely don't agree with the label "Unsalvageable". Maybe it's just semantics (I don't go into that queue because it sucks) and it really means something else, but an otherwise good question that has its good as a screenshot is *easily* salvageable, often times by any user (if an MCVE's-worth of code is included in the screenshot), not just the OP.

Comment: @TylerH What about the "easy for the editor to introduce errors or changes that would invalidate the question" part?

Comment: @user202729 I think that's grossly underestimating the ease of transcription and grossly overstating the likelihood of that kind of thing happening. It's not that hard to transcribe text without errors, even code. It's not something that people enjoy spending their time doing, typically, but that doesn't make it difficult. I have done it a few times myself for an otherwise good question.

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to vote to close a question. I leave a comment along the lines of "Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198)", but having done that, should I "skip" triaging the question, as it seems that none of the options available to me are applicable?

Comment: @sbridewell Below 3,000 reputation, you can _flag_ a question to be closed and it will put it in the close vote review queue for others to vote on, for what it's worth. I _think_ that will count as a Triage action.

Comment: Thanks for responding @TylerH. So if I choose the "flag" or "needs improvement" radio buttons, does this count as flagging a question to be closed (I notice that both popups tell me how many flags I have left today)? Only none of the reasons available seems to be a good fit for the author needing to edit their code or error message or whatever into their question as text.

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not sure, as I generally avoid the Triage queue. Hopefully someone else will respond and confirm.

Comment: @sbridewell yes flags count against your daily flag limit and are the same as clicking the "flag" link on the question. If you have close vote privileges, those close votes count against your daily limit as well.

Answer (score 25):

> but I'm not sure if it's that big of a deal

It actually makes a **big difference**.

Questions using pictures of code instead of a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be closed because they won't be searchable for future research.

> Should I review questions with screenshots of code as "Looks OK" or "Requires Editing"?

Neither, just vote to close.

These certainly require editing, but made by the OP, not anybody else. So I usually vote to close such questions, since for *editing* the OP is in charge at 1st place, and not anybody else.

Comment: I believe the last paragraph makes it look like "requires editing" could be a reasonable choice, whereas it isn't.

Comment: @yivi So I hope that's clearer wording now.