# Prohibit low-rep users from posting links to images

Tags: feature-request, images, code

No matter how much we discourage it, posters frequently write questions with all the code in an image that they link to. I personally don't think this should be a reason to close the questions -- if the image is inline, the question is usually quite understandable, it's just more of a PITA to answer since you can't copy the code to test or modify it. So I post a comment asking them to post it as plain text, but then I inline the image anyway to make the question readable.

I think the only way we'll get people not to post these links is if we outright prohibit it. So if you have too little rep, you wouldn't be allowed to post links to images at all. That will force them to paste the text.

I understand that sometimes images are useful when used in addition to the code, e.g. for screenshots of the resulting page. Perhaps it could be similar to the jsfiddle/codepen restriction: you can only post these links if you also post code. Sometimes people will get around the restriction by posting a tiny code block with all the real code in the image, but it should still be an improvement.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'd be interested in trying it too. I wonder how well it would work. It'll probably result in more people posting code as text, but it might also result in a few trying to get around the restriction by posting segments of broken half-URLs. But tolerating those would probably be better than having *so many* code-as-image questions we get nowadays

Comment: *we've been advised that this isn't a justification for closing the questions* 8 up votes and 3 down votes isn't a very strong consensus, especially when there are two comments disagreeing that have a good score.

Comment: My main issue with this suggestion is that sometimes images are better than text. For example, a display issue or something that cannot be replicated by a snippet/code. So, while sometimes images are abused, they can serve a purpose.

Comment: I absolutely close such questions. Images of code don’t count as an MRE such if it’s a debugging question then it’s going to be closed until such time we have code.

Comment: @BSMP [This link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378973) has lot more attention. Answer saying "VTC questions with images of code" has +60/-2.

Comment: I don’t see this more often than posts where images are appropriate however. I don’t see a need to take that option away.

Comment: Note that the answer there says that “it depends” and says they *add the code from the image*. They don’t leave open questions where they can’t do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters He says he does that whenthe code is short.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the link to the other question, since I misunderstood the concensus. Now I'm just saying that I don't like to close these, I'd just like to make it harder to create them.

Comment: @VLAZ As I said in the question, there are times when images are appropriate, but I think it's rare that they're *better*, they should be *in addition*.

Comment: @Barmar I do agree but...I don't see a way to enforce this with a blanket ban on images. New users will be posting bad questions no matter what measures we take. Since images *can* be useful in diagnosing an issue, I'd argue in favour of not banning them. With that said, I do recognise that images of code (or otherwise text) are a problem. I'd be in favour of measures to reduce the times these are posted. I'd just rather have something that doesn't somewhat unfairly hinder other questions.

Comment: Isn't that why I suggested they be allowed if there's also code?

Comment: There are Question types where code is not required, but an image of a problem becomes very helpful. Examples of those can be seen in the `algorithm` tag. Enforcing code in those doesn't make sense.

Comment: I do not second prohibition of posting images by low rep users. I would rather suggest to add a banner on the 'ask question' page advising the user not to post code as images of text.

Answer (score 11):

In some tags where I work images of the starting point and/or desired end-result are critical to understanding the question. I'm ***against*** this proposal.

Yes, code (and errors) posted as images are a pain. But an OP not being *able* to post an image would be a bigger problem.

I would rather curb editors who include these without VTC and/or a comment requesting the content be included as text.

Also useful would be a simple/quick way to send this message to the OP...

Comment: "without VTC": adding insult to injury, *getting answers*. My usual slightly threatening comment is "we cannot help you otherwise" – but I don't think I've *ever* seen an OP replacing image with code after they already got an answer. I mean, why bother then?

Comment: @usr2564301 That, and those who take the time to typ the code from the image.