# Allowing low rep users to post inlined images certainly isn't an improvement. Roll back please!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts, images, quality-improvement

It seems that the minimum 10 points rep restriction for posting inlined images recently was removed.

Example:  [someone can help me, I don't understand my mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697620/someone-can-help-me-i-dont-understand-my-mistake)

Showing those mostly useless screenshots only encourages new users to do that, instead of posting a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as actually required for most questions about code.
It makes it harder to argue in comments, why that's generally not OK, because it can't be correctly indexed with any common search engines.

Here's a [related request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394296/prohibit-low-rep-users-from-posting-links-to-images).

Here is the example above in its full glory for everyone:

> [image: It's a screenshot of an error with one line of text saying it's a school project that has a compilation error. It was closed for lacking debugging details and has a score of -5.]

I don't believe this was a good move, in respect to have more quality questions and content.

Anyone to agree for rolling back that change?

---

I like the proposed option at [@user3840170](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3840170/user3840170)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3840170/user3840170) a lot:

> At each upload, if the OCR detects that more than 70% of the image’s area is filled with text, reject the submission. Do not merely warn, do not even attempt to recover the recognised text, reject the submission outright. Also, blacklist known image hosts as link targets.

Comment: I know I originally said: *"It does at least warn against that explicitly in the info box on the right: "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images)""* when the announcement for the wizard came out.  But honestly, I'm still not even remotely surprised this happened.

Comment: So let me try to understand this: Instead of selecting the code, copy it to the clipboard, and paste in the question, the OP took a screenshot, used their favorite image editor to redact the screenshot, save it, and then upload it in the question? How is that an efficient workflow for anyone?

Comment: @rene Before long they'll be using a sharpie to censor it on their screen, taking a photo and uploading that.

Comment: Maybe they're just more familiar with how their phone works compared to their computer

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone knew we were going to see at least some of these, so to really gauge whether this is a regression, I think we need to know how _often_ it's occurring. If the volume is less than the amount of posts with the same lack of detail and inlined images that we were getting before, I'm actually inclined to count that as a _win_ rather than a loss.

Comment: @zcoop98 may be worth mentioning I am almost solely work here with the [tag:c++] filter on. And most of the screenshots landing there are definitely not useful from the question context. Should we differentiate along tags maybe, if these should be inlined? [tag:opencv] tagged questions might have a different requirement for some situations here for example.

Comment: Since I have some skin, down and close vote, in that game, I'll drop an unrelated opinion: It was deleted too quickly. The asker had practically no time to make corrections. I'll admit the question needed deleting given the state it was in and the asker probably would take the wrong lesson from the down and lose votes and abandon it rather than edit, but I believe the deserve the chance to prove me wrong.

Comment: New solution: instead of having a blanket ban of all images or none, import tesseract.js into the codebase. At each upload, if the OCR detects that more than 70% of the image’s area is filled with text, reject the submission. Do not merely warn, do not even attempt to recover the recognised text, ***reject the submission outright***. Also, blacklist known image hosts as link targets. Reputation-gate bypassing this filter at a 100 point threshold.

Comment: I am honestly not surprised how many users just ignore all the modal information when asking. Some of the question people have written through the wizard I look and just think "You really just didn't bother, did you. You didn't take the 30 seconds it needed to read the prompts, so I very much doubt you took the time we *expect* of you do actually, you know, try and solve this problem yourself." The images of data, I've found, have been on the increase and it's so frustrating. At least some users, however, are receptive to being told they didn't read.

Comment: @Larnu and posted a scanned pic of the exam questions, while at the middle of it  ...

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this. It was already possible for people to post pictures of text instead of the text, and they certainly did it, but now at least you can immediately see the picture instead of needing to click a link to get to it. I think it's only a problem if it makes people more likely to do that than they used to be.

Comment: " if the OCR detects that more than 70% of the image’s area is filled with text, reject the submission." is a bad solution for communities/tags which actually are about text. Take for example latex. Users frequently have to post screenshots of whole pages of text so we can which result they get and compare it to your own results.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz a site setting, perhaps? A man can dream!

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Make it tag specific :) SO *does* have an active latex tag

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz fair enough :) your dream's more robust

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I dread the moment the alarm clock will go off and stop the dream :)

Comment: [The Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQsLmEwozGM) Goldsmith at his finest.

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*.