# Recently got banned from triage, need clarity to improve my evaluation judgement

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

> Your review on triage/25728707 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing"
>   option should only be used when other community users (like you) are
>   able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better
>   shape.

Reviews from other SO members

[image]

The question

[image]

As per the definition of "Require Editing", I used the option because I noticed that the error, the user has shown is via link of an image.

Since the link can be converted to image which possibly improves the chances of being answered. I selected Require Editing.

Am I evaluating the way of improvement of question incorrectly?

Comment: Even if the images were properly edited in, would the question be on-topic for the site?

Comment: Additionally, the review ban is also for these reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25732711, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25732286, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25730058, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25732039, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25731902

Comment: I think I misinterpreted what "Require Editing" meant and kept reviewing using that logic. Thanks for clarification Samuel. Will take care in future.

Comment: Added dupe link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378971/should-i-review-questions-with-images-of-code-as-looks-ok-or-requires-editing

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving