# Audit that doesn't have full error message as text

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30516742) but if I understand the reviewing guidelines correctly the post *"Needs debugging details"* because a part of the error message is only included as an image and not as text. From the first screenshot:

> ```
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
>         ng.cmd run app:build exited with exit code 3.
>         (...)
> ```

So is the audit good? However generic the error message may be I think it's supposed to be transcribed.

Comment: That entire Q&A looks like it could do with some curation, not just the question... :/

Comment: Something tells me that this is going to end up with a situation of no consensus. Me personally I would not close this question with that reason, it should only be applied when the question is in fact not answerable in its current state. But it clearly was answered. IMO the audit did its job quite well in this case.

Comment: Re *"the error message is only included as an image and not as text"*: What is the canonical meta question for this? Is there a canned comment that could be applied?

Comment: @Gimby So, if someone answers a question with a random guess, that means the question is "answerable" and should not be closed?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) is the FAQ for text instead of images...

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, when I mean answered I don't mean "a post was created", I mean it was *answered*.

Comment: @Gimby Okay, but is it acceptable that it may have been answered by people without visual impairments because they were the only ones who could take advantage of the images of text? I'm just wondering where the limits are on how far one can push the guidelines before we start saying, "you know what, no, you screwed up, pay the price".

Comment: Images don't help the search ability for future users to find the post based on the error text. You're not going to be pasting in a screen shot of an error into a search engine you will type it in, I think the same should be expected in posting a question.

Comment: While this question would have been clearly unsalvageable if it was a screenshot of code ([How to review questions with screenshots of code in Low Quality Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382027/525036), [Don’t transcribe code from an image to text. It's just too easy to introduce new errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/525036)), I’m not sure about the consensus for errors/outputs. [It’s clearly bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/525036), but does it make them close-worthy?

Comment: Anyway, as I am not expert on the questions’ tags, and it seems you aren’t either, @bad_coder, if I were you I think [I would have just skipped it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/525036).

Comment: @DidierL *does it make them close-worthy?* Absolutely. Unless you're working with a visual programming language, or have an issue with your editor/IDE/UI or other graphical element, screenshots should only be included for reference. For command-line issues like this, copy-paste-code formatting tool is the way to go. I would have voted to close this question immediately.

Comment: This is why I never bother with review queues. I'll just stick on writing answers, comments and casting votes. SO is a hobby, and my boss is enough of an auditor for my, you know, paid, work.

Comment: The way I read that question is that it would be a good question if the OP were to replace the images with text.  The OP got his answer (but @alexelin should have been pressed to move his answer from a comment to a real answer).  It does look like it would be useful to future searchers (if the images were replaced with text).  But, looking at the close message, asking for "more debugging details" doesn't let the OP know what he/she is supposed to do.  Perhaps we need an explicit "hey, swap out the pictures with text and this can be reopened" close message

Comment: @Flydog57 The help page linked to by the close description already says "**DO NOT** use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code."

Comment: @MattDMo Fair enough. Question: if we remove the 2 images, and copy the question title inside the question body, is it still close-worthy? Note that the question title _is_ the debugging details contained in the first image. The rest of that image (that is transcribed here) appears to be irrelevant. I don’t know whether the second image helped the answerers (it looks like the useful information is provided in the `package.json` below it).

Comment: At this point I’m wondering if we are better off with a closed question containing 2 screenshots, or an open question without those screenshots (assuming it would stay open in that state).

Comment: @DidierL that's a good point, i... don't think the images themselves really add anything to the question, and the error message is in fact provided outside of the image.

Comment: Screenshots of code are (unfortunately) becoming much more prevalent. It is likely too easy to use that method compared to providing text. Or conversely, too hard to format the text properly. Is there something technical that has changed that could explain this, e.g. some new operating system feature that makes it easier to make and handle screenshots?

Comment: One thing that [did change was the syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter). Anything that is not actual code (configuration files, error messages, command-lines, etc.) is now messed up by default. But why would relatively new users care about that?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess Windows 10 has made screenshots much more easier, you just have to press Win+Shift+S to trigger the screenshot tool and take just a region of the screen. I’m wondering however if SO couldn’t implement an AI to detect screenshots of code.

Comment: @DidierL https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379871

Comment: @DidierL unfortunately I'm not enough of an SME in that area to know whether the second image is useful. I would prefer they both be transcribed (copy-pasted, really) in the question body, for indexing/search purposes and for people who use screen readers, or have imgur blocked for whatever reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, the audit was bad. These kinds of questions are useful to people having the same problem, so they get lots of upvotes. Mostly from people who don't care about the site's standards and aren't interested in enforcing them.

The question should have been (and now is) closed for lacking debugging details. An image of text is never appropriate; the error message and other textual output must be included as text. No exceptions.

You made the correct decision when reviewing in this case. That did, in fact, need to be closed. Fortunately, failing a single audit does not cause a review suspension. This is fortunate because, when audits are picked automatically by the system, there are bound to be some bad ones get in the mix.