# Why is the "very low quality" flag unavailable here?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I found the following post on the Stack Overflow:

[image: Answer]

I think the answer quality is very low, because the post provides only links to off-site resources without essential parts of the answer. Moreover, it is possible that the linked page will be changed or removed.

But the post score is greater then 0, so it is impossible to use the **very low quality** flag. Why is the flag available only for new posts scoring 0 or less?

Comment: Just flag it as not an answer, which is the right option for link-only answers anyway.

Comment: Yes, @Xufox, I agree. But I'm trying to understand the reason of the flag using restriction.

Comment: Link to answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423204/6471538

Comment: It is not particularly worse than the other answers, a lot better than the accepted answer.  Targeting this one post and not the others for scrutiny can't be the correct approach.  Look at the question, that is where it went wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant, you are right. I flagged the question post too. The above mentioned post is cited as an example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258896/295232):

> The low quality flag option will come up for zero or negatively scored posts - that's the first indication that a post is indeed low quality (or suffers from other issues).

There's another reason the VLQ option is not available; the post is older than seven days. For the motivation, see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/4751173):

> but the truth is that very few VLQ flags ever get raised on posts over 7 days old... Heck, 87% of all VLQ flags are raised on questions less than one day old. The vast, vast majority of the worst cruft gets cleaned up quickly...

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. It's probably, I would not have wondered, if the [Flag Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) page would contains clearly notes: "For old answers use the **Not an answer** flag instead."