# Where is Low Quality flag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, user-interface, flag-dialog

I wanted flag some post for its low quality ([here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839567/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-i-could-not-identify-the-error)). That post is too old (2016), but it contains *only error text* that is unuseful for most people. But there is no Low Quality flag to be used! At the same time help center says:

[image]

Is this will be fixed (added ability to use Low Quality flag) or this flag is forbidden forever and page on help center just hasn't been updated properly?

*Additional information*
I have thoroughly read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369619/why-is-the-very-low-quality-flag-unavailable-here), but it cannot help with my question.
OP in that post refers to question that is too old and VLQ(Very Low Quality) flag doesn't appear among of other flags.

Answer in that topic said (citation):

> The low quality flag option will come up for zero or negatively scored posts - that's the first indication that a post is indeed low quality (or suffers from other issues).

Another [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326585/unable-to-flag-as-very-low-quality-for-answers/326635#326635) said this (citation):

> the VLQ flag is no longer available on posts older than 7 days (the precise value may change, but 7 seems reasonable).

But for [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662314/how-to-change-the-text-displayed-in-browser-when-script-is-loading) I cannot see VLQ flag, even post is asked today, has -1 score and one edit by its author (at the time my question has been edited). Look at image below:
[image]

If there are some limitation with VLQ flag appearing, it would be good to add them to [help page center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

P.S.
[This post has 0 score; can be flagged as VLQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662277/separate-string-to-columns-by-each-character)
[This post has -1 score; cannot be flagged as VLQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658966/cannot-display-preview-you-can-post-as-is-or-try-another-link-linkedin)
Both questions asked today.

Comment: Post age has probably something to do with it. I've casted close votes on that specific question (and NAA on the answer) so it can be roomba-ed soon.

Comment: @rene, thank you. But what happened with Low Quality flag? And should help page be updated?

Comment: @gnat I read it. But why help page still contains misleading information? It would be nice to update help info according to changes.

Comment: From the help page: "5. Very low quality (i.e. no amount of editing can salvage the post) (only new posts scoring 0 or less)"

Comment: @Codeer, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657838/click-on-and-color-a-line-in-a-tiff-file). It asked today, has -1 score, but after I clicked `flag` (I didn't flag it, just look for available options) there is no option fo Low Quality flag. I think it is a bug.

Comment: @rene it's currently in the cv queue... Not sure if that should affect it though... (what's available and what goes where and why always takes me a few moments to remember...)

Comment: I just grabbed a random question with 0 score which has been asked on SO 15 hours ago. I can flag that one as VLQ.

Comment: I can also flag a new question with score -1 and a pending close-vote. So the post being in close-vote review seems not to be the reason.

Comment: @Codeer, Alright, [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662314/how-to-change-the-text-displayed-in-browser-when-script-is-loading). Asked today, edit 1 time, has -1 score. *There is no VLQ* flag.

Comment: @Codeer: [Counter Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642013/how-to-serialize-deserialize-objects-using-x-superobject), asked yesterday, score -1, edited by someone else. I can flag it

Comment: @BDL, perhaps, we can flag this question as VLQ because it has been asked yesterday. But 7 days don't gone yet.

Comment: @Dima: Maybe. But I agree with op that this is an interesting question, definitely not a duplicate of the proposed ones and should stay open.

Comment: @BDL can you post the link to that post you mentioned here as a comment and then immediately delete it please? I'll have a look at that one's timeline as well - see if there's anything that correlates...

Comment: We see the same weirdness on SU. See the transcript from [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7284263#7284263)

Comment: @JonClements: I tried, but the question I used before is closed already. I cannot reproduce it with any other question I checked. Maybe I was wrong in the first try? If I find one, I'll let you know

Comment: @rene, thank you. I read all messages. Seems it is a problem to flag question, because conditions are strange and often don't met.

Comment: @JonClements: [Found one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662981/symfony4-d%C3%A9ployment). 2 close votes, score -3, asked 15 minutes ago. [Image as proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4lsS.png)

Comment: Maybe it's caching problem? As everyone can see, I was able to flag the last example 5 minutes ago. Now the flag option is gone.

Comment: @BDL that was flagged as too broad in less than a minute of being asked...

Comment: Hm I'm now not sure this should be closed as it *does* look like a bug

Comment: okay, two recent examples you edited in make it not a dupe (retracted my vote). The answer is, VLQ flags are also hidden when question is in Triage or Close review queue. I'll post an answer explaining that (cc @JonClements)

Comment: @YvetteColomb ^^^ not a bug

Comment: @Yvette not necessarily a bug but that dupe didn't apply here... It's other logic that prevents it happening here that probably should be explained in an answer...

Comment: @JonClements they prob are dupes, but the other post didn't have a complete answer.

Comment: Is it just me or is it disturbing that I cannot flag *this* question as VLQ?

Comment: @RobertColumbia, sorry, I can't get clearly what do you meant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The system hides the option to flag a post as Very Low Quality in a few cases, namely when the post is:

- [in Triage or Close review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/165773)
- [older than 7 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/839601)
- [of positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258896/165773)

Speaking of your examples with recent non-positive score questions, one where the flag is not available is apparently under review (per the first item in the above list).

If you flag or vote to close another question and wait for several minutes until it gets into the review queue, you will notice that the VLQ flag option will become unavailable for that post as well.

<sub>An interesting effect is, since the system automatically pushes some questions into the Triage queue immediately after posting, you can find cases where the VLQ flag isn't shown from the very start. I frequently observe this in my favorite cleanup-search for [recent low score questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a-100..-4%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano).</sub>

Comment: (side note) list of cases has been copied from my MSE post: [Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283357/165773)

Comment: Thank you, gnat! Your answer explains why some of question (which I have seen) cannot be flagged as VLQ. The problem lied in review of new questions. As regular user who cannot know if question is under review, I thought it was a bug.

Comment: I don't think either of our answers are actually correct. The flag shows up when there's close votes on a post. A close vote puts a post into the close vote review queue.

Comment: @YvetteColomb no, everything here is correct and I tested that many times. Close vote pushes question into the queue with some delay - that's why you can see flag option for few minutes after it was cast. Another case when it is shown is when question has left the queue by expiration or by leave open votes, this is also when you can see VLQ flag option on a question with close votes

Comment: @gnat updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: see also [Unable to retract VLQ flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333569/839601)

Answer (score 10):

### TL;DR

The Low Quality Flag won't be an option for a question if *any* of the following conditions are met:

- it's older than 7 days
- it has an answer
- it's upvoted
- is in the triage queue
- is in the close vote queue

see also [Flag Options Missing - Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187641/flag-options-missing-is-this-a-bug)

---

Well there's clearly some doubt about what causes this flag option to hide.

[Very Low Quality flag not shown for question at -1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111120/very-low-quality-flag-not-shown-for-question-at-1)

- We now suppress the "very low quality" option. It is only available on closed questions or posts with a score less than 1.([From Nov 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/proposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers/110754#110754))

Now the post doesn't need to be closed.

From [Dec 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/310756):

> ### Changes to VLQ flag availability
>
> So as of a few minutes ago, Very Low Quality won't be an option from within Triage review or from anywhere else while a question is being triaged. We're also taking this opportunity to be a bit proactive with another change that'll be necessary soon: Very Low Quality won't be available for questions that are currently undergoing Close review either.

Also see here [Why is the "very low quality" flag unavailable here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369619/why-is-the-very-low-quality-flag-unavailable-here)

Note: this doesn't explain why a question with a close vote will still show the low quality flag dialog. As a close vote will automatically put a post into the close vote review queue.

As shown in [this diagram](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/310756):

[image]

There is a delay between close voting and the post being in the review queue. A "job" runs every five minutes on the main site to put posts into the review queues. Courtesy [Mayken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374977/where-is-low-quality-flag/374982?noredirect=1#comment636213_374982).

Also worth noting the [flag options change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246220/why-the-flag-option-very-low-quality-is-missing-in-a-question) once a post is closed.

Comment: Nice answer too, I vote for it. Yvette, because you are a moderator, could you make a link to gnat's answer and place it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to make a situation with flags *more* clearer. Honestly, for me it was very difficult to get why I can't flag question as VLQ (question already deleted).

Comment: @Dima let me run it by another mod first. Not a bad idea.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2nd and 4th point are correct? [I can flag as low-quality although close-votes are present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4lsS.png) and [I can flag when there is an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRdZs.png).

Comment: @Dima actually mods cannot edit that page.

Comment: @BDL no I'm was doing detective work on it. Cripes.

Comment: I think it's about beeing in review, not about having close-votes attached. Answers don't seem to play a role at all (at least I can flag no matter what the score of the answer is).

Comment: Yvette, perhaps, you knows someone who is able to do this?

Comment: @BDL a close vote will toss it into the close review queue.

Comment: @Dima perhaps write another question? that way the team can see it.

Comment: Interesting this got a down vote and the other didn't, yet we say the same things, but differently. A close vote will put a post into the close vote review queue, essentially saying the same thing as Gnat.

Comment: Yvette, I thought moderators have their own canals for communication. Alright, should I do this here or use `meta.stackexchange`?

Comment: @Dima you could put it on meta,stackexchange. Check the faq there first. Mods are limited in what we can do. We're more of less exception handlers. We can edit some features of the website. It is done so sparingly, I am not sure which parts of it we can.

Comment: Thank you, Yvette. I definitely will do that.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: The downvote is from me. And as I already proofed with screenshots, having close-votes does not prevent low-quality flags. Same goes for answers. What else than screenshots showing that I can flag under these conditions could I add to show why the answer is wrong?

Comment: @BDL I'm going to ask a community manager to give us a complete answer.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: Thanks, that sounds great :)

Comment: @Dima make sure it has not already been asked!

Comment: Yvette, thanks for notice. Obviously I must wait for CM's answer and only after post request on `meta.stackexchange`.

Comment: @Dima yeh I pinged Shog, he'll have a look at this when he's about and has time

Comment: I bet Taryn had a lot of fun making that flowchart

Comment: Yes, there is a delay between casting a close vote and the question entering the CV queue. When I looked at it, it appeared that the task to move things into CV queue ran on 5 minute intervals on Sack Overflow. It was mentioned that the interval for that task is 20 minutes on meta.SE, so it may be different on other sites.

Comment: There are a few ways that a question can leave the close-vote review queue: The flags/votes can age away (start aging away 4 days from last vote if views >=100; start aging away 14 days from last vote if views<100 ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/271271))). The question can be edited *from the close-vote review queue* (i.e. the [blue "Edit" button](//i.stack.imgur.com/plX9o.png)). The review can be completed (i.e. enough "Leave Open" review results). A mod votes "Leave Open" from the review queue (doesn't cancel close-votes; just kicks it out of the queue).

Comment: @Makyen so as I can see there is no problem if a question has close-votes and also can be marked as VLQ?

Comment: @Dima As far as I know, it doesn't inherently indicate a problem *with the site*. It likely indicates there's either a disagreement with how the question should be handled, and/or that someone edited from the close-vote review queue without resolving the problems which caused people to vote/flag for closure (the editor probably didn't understand that editing *from review* removes the post from the queue). Unfortunately, editing from review queues without resolving all the issues for the post being in the queue is quite common and results in the post being removed from the queue in all cases.

Comment: However, flagging a question as VLQ is almost never the correct choice. A VLQ flag on a question puts the question in the Triage queue. It effectively is just asking several other users to look at the question and decide if it should be edited ("Requires Editing" & moves it to the Help & Improvement Queue), or should be closed ("Unsalvageable" & moves it to the Close Vote Queue). Better would be to either just edit/suggest an edit (applies the edit directly, or if < 2k rep puts the edit in the Suggested Edits Queue) or vote/flag for closure (puts the question (back) in the Close Vote Queue).

Comment: @Makyen thank you for clarification. I just was wonder why help states *one thing* while the real situation is totally *different*.