# What flag can I use if I can't use a Very Low Quality flag?

Tags: support, flags

When the post (Question OR answer) is over 7 days old, or when it has a positive score, or both, I can't use the VLQ flag.  However, if the post DOES meet the VLQ condition, which flag should I use?

---

Update: Alexei says:

> It is never appropriate to use custom flag with "Very Low Quality" as an explanation.

Cody Gray also says:

> The better way to think about it is, there is no difference between VLQ and NAA flags on answers.

I don't get it.  NAA and VLQ flags are different, and you cannot treat them the same.  Even on answers.

One time, on A&M SE, this had happened:

> [image: declined]

Comment: VLQ applies to answers, are you trying to flag a question? And if so, there is probably a better flag to use - "Unclear" or "Needs focus" are usually applicable where you'd otherwise might be tempted to use VLQ.

Comment: @VLAZ - Both questions AND answers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We (debatably?) **could** raise a custom VLQ flag if (only) the original VLQ flag option isn't available.

This is the attachment shown on my question:

> [image]

If you see the flag decline reason, it totally makes sense.

We can raise the same custom flag on both questions and answers, in this view.

> [image]

Please note that the  "**V**ery low quality" flag is the custom flag, and not the standard "**v**ery low quality" flag, which was not available when I was flagging.

Comment: This is not a practice we accept here on Stack Overflow. Moderators on *other* sites in the network may accept these, but smaller sites have very different moderation challenges from Stack Overflow. I note that these screenshots are of flags raised on posts on a different site in the SE network.

Answer (score 8):

It is never appropriate to use custom flag with "Very Low Quality" as an explanation.

What you should use instead - downvote (you need a bit more - 125 - [rep for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)) on both questions and answers, flag to close on questions.

NAA/VLQ flags are for posts that are posted as an "answer" but do not provide the answer *at all* and do not look like an answer. VLQ is more for posts that look like comments or link only, NAA for complete gibberish.

For questions usually you need to vote/flag to close, most likely using "needs detail or clarity" as a reason.

Custom flags are for cases where standard flags/actions (like edits, comments, vote to close and downvotes) are not enough or not applicable. Such flag must have a clear explanation why standard actions can't be applied by any member of community (i.e. "can't close question with bounty"). Note that "I don't have reputation to {edit/close/vote/comment}" is not a reason for custom flag unless content is actively harmful and you are quite sure that no members of community will be able to deal with it in next several days.

Note that using flags inappropriately will cause flag ban (which I believe block all flagging except "custom").

You may not see VLQ flagging either because you are banned from flagging (see [Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) if it applies to you), or you are trying to flag a positively scored/old answer - [Why is the "very low quality" flag unavailable here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369619/why-is-the-very-low-quality-flag-unavailable-here?rq=1)).

Comment: Once a post has been upvoted the VLQ flag option is disabled. Which tells you all you need to know why moderators will decline an unqualified custom VLQ flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, updated answer with reasons why VLQ is not available.

Comment: I think you have NAA and VLQ the wrong way round in your paragraph #3.

Comment: The better way to think about it is, there is **no difference** between VLQ and NAA flags on answers. On questions, VLQ means "needs to be immediately deleted, without going through the normal close process". On answers, VLQ and NAA mean essentially the same thing: "garbage that cannot be salvaged and needs to be immediately deleted by a moderator".

Comment: Alexei, the VLQ and NAA you went the other way around in your 3rd par.

Comment: @CodyGray Would your VLQ/NAA equivalence also hold true for link-only answers? I've always assumed that NAA flags on these don't go to the mod queues.

Comment: As Adrian Mole have said, it is the other way around.  NAA is like **"Can ♭VIIㅡi in a minor key still be called a Leading-tone IAC?"** while VLQ is like **"Ñ¡(○-ñ¡(○-ñ¡¡~♡"**

Comment: @Adrian Yes. It doesn't matter what the problem is with the answer. If it needs to be deleted, then you should flag it. Both NAA and VLQ flags are handled in exactly the same way. They put the question into the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, where they can be reviewed and deleted by the community. After they've been in that queue for an hour, they start showing up in the mod flag queue. Mods can also check a box to show these posts, even if they haven't been in LQP for an hour, so there's no way to know whether they'll be handled by the community or by a mod.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your feedback! TBH, I was wee bit confused as to how flagging as NAA in the (say) Late Answers queue and "Recommend Deletion" in the LQPQ (I could call my pet dog, that, if I had one) worked together. Now I'm not confused - except for the fact that the LQPQ *seems* to give me a pseudo-vote-to-delete privilege without having the required rep.

Comment: @Adrian It is exactly a pseudo-delete privilege. If enough reviewers without delete privileges recommend deletion, the post can, in fact, be deleted. Posts flagged in Late Answers and First Posts end up in the Low Quality Posts review queue (and/or the diamond mod queue), where they generally end up deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray - no, NAAs are more of an "answer" which should rather be a comment / another question / or some other post.  Even on answers, NAA and VLQ are very different.  VLQ is more like it has serious content / formatting problems and need to be removed.

Comment: NAA is more like: "Sorry, but I could not understand what you are asking.  Can you please clarify?"

Comment: VLQ is more like: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

Comment: Related: [*Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/1364007)

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya No, that is not correct. Moderators nor anyone else makes any distinction between NAA and VLQ flags on answers. They are used and handled interchangeably, to mean “this needs to be deleted”, just as I said above.

Comment: @CodyGray uhm, Maika id correctly summarise the guidance for NAA and VLQ there, and I generally see them used that way too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes.  So if there is no vlq option, what would you do?  Raise a custom flag?

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya if a post is so terrible that it requires a moderator to deal with it (i.e. it can’t wait for or won’t gain enough regular community members to cast delete votes on it, over time, and “Not An Answer” flag on an answer or a close vote on a question won’t do), *then* use a custom flag and explain, clearly, what you want done to the post and why. E.g. “This answer is nonsense, because .... Please delete it, as not enough users with delete votes are active in this specific tag”, etc.

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya: remember however that we don’t make technical calls or enforce the rules of third parties. Answers are not deleted just because they are wrong or outdated. Questions are not closed by moderators just because it’s about an ongoing competition or the concepts could possibly be used to do something illegal.

Comment: See my edited question.