# There should be at least 15 or 14 items for the Asian dynasty and 25 or more items for war chiefs

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags, english

**There should be at least 15 or 14 items for the Asian dynasty and 25 or more items for war chiefs**
...or how to deal with obviously auto-translated content.

[How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) says that "Answers written in non-English should be flagged as very low quality, although not an answer will also work."

**What should be done though with answers that do look English, but actually badly butchered auto-translation to the point of not making sense?**

I'm not talking about someone who is non-native English speaker and writes with some mistakes or non-native sounding sentences, but about very obvious machine translation that produces something that nobody who have any remote command of English would write. The quote in title (or in first line if somebody would find title too gibberish - because it is - and edit it) comes my old declined flag on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32071090/936986

[image: answer preserved for posterity, since it's now deleted1]

It already looks wrong - since question asks how to fix error from programming standpoint and answer seems to answer from user perspective, but I can't really be sure about that or even anything in this answer with all the Asian dynasties, war chiefs, massages and walla in it - i.e. stuff that obviously not connected to InstallShield errors at all.

IMO stuff like that is indecipherable noise that should be treated exactly like answers in non-English.

Comment: The answer also looks _plagiarized_ and then translated.

Comment: I like that someone fixed the formatting of the answer and went on their daily business :). It does seem to attempt to answer the question (maybe?). Probably the best course of action is simply deleting it.

Comment: That looks like poor English to me - AOE TAD/War Chiefs sounds like Age of Empire Asian Dynasties, and "voila" -> "walla" and "there" -> "they're" is a human, not a machine error! The answerer obviously totally misunderstood the question, though!

Comment: Agreed with @KenY-N: The person answering the question clearly answered the wrong question: they thought the question was how to avoid the issue when installing a game, not how to avoid it as a developer.  That answer might be responsive for a similar question on Super User.

Comment: Gibberish should be flagged as VLQ.

Comment: "Massage" is a common misspelling of "Message" for non-native speakers. "you may or may not get a message not able to copy something something(temp 0002) or (temp 0001) just press the skip button till it finishes." makes sense.

Comment: @CodyGray what would you recommend for posts [older than 7 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/839601) (which don't allow VLQ flags)?

Comment: "my old declined flag on this answer"... a flag on this got declined? Why? As somebody who's worked with InstallShield, even I assume the answerer got every single noun wrong I still can't figure out how this is even remotely relevant. Domain knowledge and bad translations aside, how is "copy stuff to a USB stick" a reasonable answer to anything? What made this salvageable?

Comment: It has been deleted now

Comment: IMO, this sounds like someone speaking into a dictation software that makes some mistakes, lacking correct punctuation, and lacking correct capitalization. Ken Y-N states examples of some of what I'm talking about in a comment above. There's also a "you're" => "your" near the end. The stream of consciousness seems somewhat evident with the incorrect order of "15 or 14".

Comment: All your base are belong to roomba.

Answer (score 49):

### This isn't what you think it is.

As Ken Y-N's comment above explains, this is an answer (admittedly likely by someone not particularly fluent in English) on how to avoid the error OP asked about, except *as a user experiencing it while installing a specific product*: Age of Empires III: The Asian Dynasties (and AoE III: The WarChiefs). It's not a "horribly garbled failure at auto-translation", most likely.

Either way, what's clear is that it does not address the question being asked. You should downvote such answers for sure (that's our most important quality control tool on Stack Overflow!), and then flag as Very Low Quality if the post is still eligible for such a flag (the post's age and score can make that tricky sometimes), and hope that the system will handle it properly.

Additionally, it would be helpful to leave a comment explaining how this looks like gibberish and asking the poster if they perhaps meant to post this somewhere else, or somehow made some other mistake by posting that content where they did. In other words, give them the opportunity to fix the issue without further intervention from the community.

If it's too old to flag for VLQ, I would not recommend custom flagging; in my experience moderators tend to decline flags on answers that should be deleted since some community members do have the ability to cast delete votes on negatively-scored answers.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, the answerer likely found the fix for their broken AoE install, looked for a place to post it, and posted it here without a great deal of thought. Still, the question is unambiguously geared toward people *developing* installshield installers (not using them as end-users) and the answerer should have either looked for a more fitting question or made one (e.g., on a gaming focused stack exchange or somewhere else).

Answer (score -3):

What you should be reacting to here above all else, is that **the question and all answers are about how to install a piece of software, not about programming**.

It is blatantly off-topic - you should start by ensuring that the *question* is closed and down-voted before anything else. It may or may not be on-topic on the Super User site but never here.

Once the question is closed, you may worry about accepted or up-voted answers of low quality, because those block closed questions from getting auto-deleted. Down vote all of them for being blatantly off-topic.

Why some people are casting up-votes and re-open votes on the question is truly beyond me.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's necessarily off-topic as it's unclear if it's their own install script or if it's of a third-party package, but it should at least be closed for "Needs details or clarity", and since it's over 10 years old the likelihood of getting any new info is minimal.

Comment: @KenY-N "Sometimes, when running an InstallShield installation" seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: I can see why you'd interpret it that way, but considering the post contains things like "Also, I doubt that there is actually a problem with the strings;", and the answer contains "In InstallShield 2009, if the "Setup Launcher Type" field (on the "Setup" tab of a release) is set to Unicode", I would say it's undeniable that the OP is attempting to debug an Installer program *they wrote*, I have to disagree with you here, I'm nearly 100% sure these are things that only an *installer developer* would run into.

Comment: I'm going off of memory here admittedly (since I haven't made an Installshield installer in nearly 10 years), there is a chance that erm (this is hard to say)... installshield's own installer to install Installshield also presents you with these setup options, and the OP is troubleshooting a bad configuration option of installshield itself, but I don't think this is the case, and even if it were, it's still a question about a programming tool, and it'd be something best answered by a programmer, not a general IT person.