# Make it clearer when the Triage queue is full

Tags: feature-request, triage

So on today's episode of `Things I learned through Meta` there's [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage) (emphasis mine)

> Current triage settings work… but there are problems
>
> The queue handles a lot of questions. Since it was launched, nearly 1.1 million posts have been triaged - an average of 60k+ a month. Depending on the month, anywhere from 17% to 27% of all questions asked go through Triage.
>
> Triage reviews the newest questions and they should be handled in a reasonable amount of time (no huge backlog like Close Review), in order for this to work, we have safeguards in place to control what hits the queue.
>
> Some of the limits include:
>
> - The question must have been asked in the past 7 days
> - **The maximum queue size is 100 items at any moment**
>
> While we've processed a ton of questions with the current settings, the limits are...well, limiting. **This results in some questions being pushed to triage, then immediately kicked out for a variety of reasons.**
>
> That might not sound like a huge issue, **but when a question bypasses triage it goes directly into the moderator flag queue, meaning our human exception handlers need to process it.** Moderators are supposed to deal with exceptional things and most of these questions don't qualify for that.

It would be helpful to know this when looking at the Review page. If you're looking to help review, there's nothing to let you know "Hey! Starting here would be helpful!". Make it stand out in the page more. Something like this

[image]