# Has there been an increment of Triage review limits?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I just found out that I could review additional 20 posts under `Triage` category.

Is this something newly implemented?

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, we just made a slight change in the settings.  As of about an hour ago, we made 2 changes:

- Triage will now hold a maximum number of 200 posts to review
- If the queue is larger than 150 items, then you get 40 reviews

This is part of our ongoing effort to adjust the [settings in Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage) and [other queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science).

Comment: Great! I think it will serve it's purpose well, @bluefeet :)