# Why has my review triage limit changed?

Tags: support, triage

For many months, I have been seeing this message when I finish reviewing 20 triage questions:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 triage questions; come back in 6 hours to
>   continue reviewing.

Yesterday, however, my limit on how many questions I could review jumped from 20 to 40, and I was told that I could come back in three hours to continue reviewing:

> Thank you for reviewing 40 triage questions; come back in 3 hours to
>   continue reviewing.

Today however, my limit has been reduced back down to 20 (it has been around 24 hours). Is it normal for this to happen?

Comment: Check out [this answer:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332283/2607247) _"The limit is dynamic..."_ (That small quote quickly explains, there's more explanation in the answer.) There's also [this answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335064/review-message-says-i-reviewed-20-but-history-says-i-reviewed-40/335066#335066)

Comment: Well, that makes more sense then. Those answers, and [this one from Bluefeet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331667/2607247) cover it, then. :)

Comment: So if I've completed 20 reviews, but the queue is then larger than 150 and it has been less than 6 hours, can I review the other 20?

Comment: Yes, you can, since the queue is dynamic. Likewise, if you start reviewing that other 20, and in that time the queue drops below 150, you'll be stopped right there and not when you hit 40.