# What if Triage wasn't capped?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, triage

From [Fixing the disconnect between VLQ and Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage) (emphasis added):

> While we've processed a ton of questions with the current settings, the limits are...well, limiting. **This results in some questions being pushed to triage, then immediately kicked out for a variety of reasons.**

The potent solution to this problem is to give [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) infinite capacity - that is, its backlog will be able to hold an infinite number of questions.

Yes, it sounds scary.

But the thing is **we haven't tried it, therefore we don't know if we can handle a Triage that can grow indefinitely!** We should try it - if things go haywire and the queue surpasses [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), we can simply bring the limit back.

Comment: [4, 5, 6...test!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319131/4099593)

Comment: 4,294 reviews today.  On a Saturday.  Damn, what an enormous waste of energy with so little to show for it.  You need more??

Comment: What if we would close and delete all the crap?;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, isn't Triage's goal to identify crap?

Comment: I'm not sure. I mean, I believe we're very good at identifying crap. We're very bad at closing it. Frankly, one daunting queue with an unbeatable backlog is more than enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comment by Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334287/what-if-triage-wasnt-capped#comment393862_334287), we've been doing a lot of [checking, testing, adjusting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage), then more checking and [tweaking of the Triage review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/426671).

[Triage was built](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) to quickly handle new questions. The key here is to **handle questions quickly**.  If we uncapped Triage, then that kind of defeats the purpose of the quickness of the review.   We'd never want Triage to grow to be the size of, let's say, the Close Review queue.  We have very specific requirements in place for what hits Triage and a cap is one of those requirements to prevent a large backlog.

Now, just because we aren't going to uncap Triage doesn't mean we're done trying to improve the workflow of the queue.  Based on your question, I decided to take a look at how many questions were eligible for Triage vs. how many were actually reviewed by Triage to see if there were any improvements we could make.

[image: Triage]

Prior to the [increase in queue for Triage from 100 to 200 items at a time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/426671) (around August 4th), we were averaging about 65% review of eligible questions in the queue. We adjusted the settings and number of questions reviewed jumped to about 90% of the eligible posts...in other words it was a huge improvement.  Around the beginning of September, the number of eligible questions increased (most likely due to school starting). The increase was enough that review wasn't able to keep up with the demand.

That brings us to today, or I should say Friday, when I started looking at this.  The criterion for a question to hit Triage had not been adjusted in quite some time, so we reviewed them and on Friday we make a little tweak to the settings.  This should actually limit the number of questions that are eligible for Triage review.

Based on the little adjustment we're back to reviewing about 95% of the posts that are eligible. Is this the only fix we're going to make?  No. We're going to keep an eye on the settings to see if there is anything else that we should fine tune on down the road, but uncapping won't be one of them.

Comment: In the other linked [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science), Did you (or the other devs) consider Brad's second suggestion of reducing the number of reviews needed to delete a post from LQPQ? (I'm sure that you can simulate the difference that'd be caused if the number of <20k reviewers needed is 5 instead of 6 by using the present data).

Comment: No, we have not looked at that @BhargavRao

Answer (score 35):

We already have a decent guess at what would happen. Recently, [the Triage limit was bumped from 100 to 200 posts](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5156717#5156717) in the queue at any given time. What happened?

[image: Triage queue stats]

Triage reached a new equilibrium peak of 200. Now, let's compare Triage with some other queues:

[image]

Triage would probably be most like Low Quality Posts, in reaching a large peak before falling eventually, with about a weekly cycle. Similarly, Triage takes in questions with a low quality score, and Low Quality Posts does the same with answers. However, Low Quality Posts does have less reviewers, with Triage only having a reputation limit of 500 and Low Quality Posts having a limit of 2000.

So theoretically, this *could* work. However, Triage's whole point is to be quick (hence the name Triage). Low Quality Posts generally has a 1-2 day backlog of posts -- when you're dealing with questions, the boat has already sailed in that timeframe. So, while this could work, I don't think having an unlimited queue would be good. Perhaps increasing the limit might work, but there has to be an optimization of time to review vs. queue size.

Comment: Regarding your last point - perhaps if questions timed out of Triage? So, if it's been in there too long, it's automatically moved on to LQP or something.

Comment: @anaximander As it stands right now there is no other place for the Q to go.  LQPQ is answers only so the only other place you could possibly drop it would be the CVQ unless you want to make a new queue or start having Q's in the LQPQ again.

Comment: @NathanOliver What I meant by "or something" is that depending on how the stats turn out, it may be decided that a post that's sat in Triage long enough to expire might get an automatic "Looks OK" on the principle that a question that hasn't been downvoted or close-voted it in that amount of time is probably not *too* bad. Of course, that's optimistic, but like I said, let's see how the stats turn out.