# On the performance of the low quality review queue

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, statistics

If you are able to [understand Shog's graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340865/792066) you will notice that NAAs handled by the moderators are twice as much as those handled by "community", which considering that the community is more strict handling NAAs (there's a stat saying that community tend to reject more flags on the low quality review queue than moderators, can't find it) it doesn't make sense that the ["exception handlers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) handle something so mundane like NAA flags where the community could, arguably, do this job.

Taking into account the above, I think we are incurring an opportunity cost by not allowing the community to handle more flags (since there are many more users than moderators, moderators' time is more valuable). But for that we need the data to identify if this hypothesis holds any water or if there is something else at play.

For that I would need the following:

- Number of NAA/VLQ flags on answers that had to be elevated to the moderator queue (not being handled on the LQRQ), the reason was:

  - The answer was score >0
  - The answer was accepted
  - [The timeout was reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/213575) (one hour after the flag is raised, it moves to the moderator queue)

    - What was the LQRQ leaning towards, and it agreed with the action taken by the moderator?
- Break down of number of flags handled by the LQRQ in 5 minute brackets and its outcome. (I think average, std and median should be given as general measure too)

That would help us to identify whenever the LQRQ needs tuning and what exactly needs to be tuned.

Comment: As a moderator, it's very easy to observe that the Low Quality Posts review queue is unable to handle the volume of "very low quality" and "not an answer" flags that come in at present. If moderators do not handle a significant volume of these, that queue backs up immediately. I've seen this happen again and again with the ebb and flow of the size of the overall moderator flag queue. I've [made a couple of proposals related to this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319133/19679), one of which [has been partially implemented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/19679).

Comment: Bunch of tangentially-relevant stuff here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i/340905#340905

Comment: For analysis, I'd split "not an answer" flags apart from the "very low quality" ones, because as you can see from those stats these are handled differently (67.6% moderator handled for the former, 32.1% for the latter). While it would be great for the community to handle more of the "not an answer" flags, the vast majority are trivial to process by moderators. When 90+% percent of them are on obvious gibberish or follow-on questions, they're easy to handle. The narrow scope of the flag makes these easier to process, as compared to the fuzzy nature of VLQ, which I tend to avoid handling.

Comment: @BradLarson from my point of view, a moderator handling NAA's is a waste of time, basically because community can (and should) be able to handle those on their own. Even if you handle 10k NAA's flag vs sussing out a voting ring, the later is a more productive use of your time, since no one but a moderator can do it.

Comment: @Braiam - I agree that eventually the tooling should move to a stage where the community handles everything but a handful of tasks, and [talked about a long-term vision for that here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251177/19679), but in the short term I'd look at dealing with "very low quality" and "not an answer" flags in different ways. They are handled differently, and I'd put more effort into figuring out how the community could handle the remaining 32.1% of the "very low quality" flags in a sustainable way, instead of how it could take on more "not an answer" flags right now.

Comment: @BradLarson All you need to do to have the community handle them is stop having the moderators spending so much time on it.  The community handles them just fine, but lots of mods spend lots of time handling flags like this when they're only a few minutes old.  No new tooling is needed; the mods just need to ignore these flags.  (And if they can't, then the only tooling change would be to not show these flags to mods.)

Comment: @Servy the thing is that they can't ignore it... once it's on their queues, it's out our queues, and all bets are off.

Comment: @Braiam That's actually not correct.  While the mods don't get the flag for 60 minutes, once they see it in their dashboard, it can also exist in the review queue.

Comment: @Servy - [I'd love for all "very low quality" flags to be hidden from moderators completely](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340873/19679), but community review is currently unable to keep pace with the rate of items coming into this review queue. Changes would first need to be made to offset the increased volume and make this more sustainable. There are roughly three times as many "not an answer" flags coming in, and moderators handle many more of those, so a more radical rethinking of the process would be needed for the community to handle these as well.

Comment: @Servy The mods don't see NAA/VLQ flags on most posts for 60 minutes, there is a delay in the process for the queue to handle it.  The problem is that the queue doesn't process them fast enough which leads them to be handled by the mods.

Comment: @bluefeet well, I was always working on the assumption that they are on one or the other.

Comment: @bluefeet now, serious question, why it has to be handled "fast"? I would expect NAA's to get a comment pretty fast, saying that it's NAA, which could motivate the author to delete the answer themselves. I don't see why it should be handled with such speed.

Comment: @Servy: did you read the first comment Brad posted? Us moderators have left the NAA and VLQ queues be often enough, only to see it spiral out of control. So no, the community is **not** handling them just fine. Also, it is not 'lots' of mods spending 'lots' of time on these flags. On a good day, I handle maybe 100 - 150, but only because I process hundreds of flags in general, every day. There is only one other moderator that processes flags in that kind of volume.  Clearing out some NAAs is a nice distraction from the drudgery of other flag types, I certainly don't see it as a waste of time.

Comment: @Braiam I'm trying to pull the numbers on this, but from my experience these items tend to linger in the review queue for days before being handled.  That's not necessarily happening right now because the flag queue is under control, but when the flag queue hovers near 2k we've had NAA/VLQ flags stick around for days and the community hasn't handled them.

Comment: To add to what Brad, Martijn and bluefeet have already stated... One need only look back a few months to find numerous "why aren't my flags being handled?" questions as a counterpoint to the recent spat of "why are my flags being declined?" - when posts, *especially* difficult/borderline posts languish in a queue, that doesn't really solve anything.

Comment: Well, then lets look at what is the inflection point, were speed meets accuracy cum sanity... no?

Comment: There seem to be multiple overlapping issues. One of the issues is community engagement in the review queues. Part of the problem with questions languishing in the various review queues is that the instructions to reviewers are not clear (multiple meta posts). In addition, what the effects are from the various queues are not clearly spelled out to reviewers. These are just text changes that should have been improved long ago, but, for some reason, have not been. Having these be clear would improve the quality of reviews we get and help retain the people who are conscientiously doing reviews.

Comment: An improvement that has been made is to display the number of review tasks rather than just the number of pending edit reviews. Most of the times that I have checked out the review queues, there have been relatively few posts in the LQP review queue. Having the number of posts that are in the queues displayed at the top of each page helps indicate when we should lend a hand. It would be nice if it was configurable (e.g. display a total with those queues in which we have interest, queue totals individually (lots of empty screen real estate there), or when specific queues get long, etc.).

Comment: If the community really isn't able to handle the load in the LQP queue (which is a *very* surprising claim, given that in *years* I've *never* seen it go above a backlog of 200 posts, and frequently can't review because it's empty), then an obvious way to help lessen the load on mods would be to filter flags off to the mods *at input time into the queue*, rather than after they've been there for some time period (and likely already attracted *almost* enough reviews to be handled). The current approach, as I understand it, is effectively optimised to waste the maximum amount of reviewer effort.

Comment: @BradLarson one of the reasons the queue backs up immediately is that you need like 6+ "recommend deletion" votes to actually get something deleted in that queue unless 20k users are reviewing more. Maybe look at getting that changed to 3 users = deleted period.

Comment: @Magisch, Brad has spoken about reducing the number of reviews needed before, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319133/4099593, But when I asked bluefeet later about the same, bluefeet mentioned that they are not looking at it http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334287/what-if-triage-wasnt-capped/335279#comment399620_335279. But bluefeet clearly mentioned that the team is looking into Brad's 1st suggestion there.

Comment: @MarkAmery,  I've seen the LQPQ cross 800 in the [last week of Oct](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=33743073#33743073). I remember that in that particular week the [queue never came below 750](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=33632000#33632000).

Comment: I have never seen suggested that the community is more likely to reject an NaA flag than a moderator. Never. Not ever. In fact, a great number of reviewers in the LQPRQ are [doing it wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), and validating flags which should not have been cast.

Comment: @TinyGiant funny that you say that, because it was said after the naa's were feed into the LQRQ that moderators and community behave more or less the same on those flags (86% post result in deletion if I recall correctly). BTW, the NAA's handled by moderators [where helpful in a 95% of the time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340905/792066)

Answer (score 11):

### tl;dr;

A very small percentage of VLQ & NAA flags bypass the review queue and go directly to the moderators. The vast majority of these flags go directly to the LQRQ review queue to handle, but most reviews are taking over 4 hours to complete. As a result, the moderators are stepping in and handling flags.

It seems that the [current review settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/164200) aren't allowing the community to review flags in a timely manner, so we might need to do some adjusting.

---

Over the past year, I've thought a lot about [VLQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage) & NAA flags, as well as [review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science).  We performed a few tests, made some adjustments to the how review works, but maybe it's time for more tweaks.

As requested, here are some additional details about flags in 2016.

**Total Flags**

```
+------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| Flag |  Total  | Mod Handled | Community Handled |
+------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| NAA  | 284,408 | 192,394     | 92,014            |
| VLQ  | 74,801  | 29,758      | 45,043            |
+------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
```

The result of these flags were:

```
+------+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| Flag |     Result      |  Total  | Mod Handled | Community Handled |
+------+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| NAA  | Helpful         | 263,375 | 184,138     | 79,237            |
| NAA  | Disputed*       | 12,304  | 147         | 12,157            |
| NAA  | Declined        | 8,109   | 8,109       | 0                 |
| NAA  | Self Clear**    | 620     | 0           | 620               |
+------+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| VLQ  | Helpful         | 65,479  | 27,135      | 38,344            |
| VLQ  | Disputed*       | 6,569   | 59          | 6510              |
| VLQ  | Declined        | 2,564   | 2,564       | 0                 |
| VLQ  | Self Clear**    | 188     | 0           | 188               |
| VLQ  | User Deleted*** | 1       | 0           | 1                 |
+------+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Notes:

*If a mod enters a review queue, they will cast the binding vote on the flag in the queue which is why there can be disputed flags

**Self Clear occurs when a user [retracts a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

***User Deleted is when a user is deleted from the site, the flag is cleared

#### But, how many flags skip the Low Quality Review Queue?

NAA and VLQ flags bypass the LQRQ under the following circumstances and go directly to the mod queue:

- the answer is accepted
- the post previously was in the LQRQ review queue, completed a full review cycle,  wasn't deleted, and has received additional NAA/VLQ flags

In 2016, there were 3,779 flags on accepted answers, and 1,561 flags that bypassed the LQRQ due to a previous review.

A note about this:

- The total number of flags bypassing the LQRQ are approximate, due to the sync job running every five minutes. This can result in items possibly being resolved before getting captured by the job.

#### How are posts hitting the low quality review queue being handled?

As [Shog mentioned in his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341690/on-the-performance-of-the-low-quality-review-queue#comment433611_341690), just look back a few months on Meta, and people were complaining about flags taking a long time to be handled.  This made me curious about how quickly VLQ and NAA flags are being handled now. I took a look at the average number of minutes between creation and handling time of these flags over 2016. You'll notice that [since the November election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8), there has been a significant drop in how long it's taking for VLQ and NAA flags to be processed.  This is because the queue is no longer averaging 2k+ flags on a daily basis, we're now hovering around a few hundred.

> [image]

We get a very similar picture when looking at the average amount of time (in minutes) posts spend in the Low Quality Review Queue:

> [image]

While these images give an overview, there isn't a lot we can take away from it.  The biggest initial takeaway is that the review queue isn't able to keep up with the posts hitting the queue, so things tend to sit and wait to be handled.

The Low Quality review queue is given 60 minutes to handle a post before it's also sent to the moderator queue.  Once it's in both places, either the mods or the review queue can process the flag.  I wanted to see how long it was taking for flags to be handled over the past year, by looking at different time frames ([visual of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTAs1.png)):

```
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|   Month    | # Flags < 60 mins | # Flags 60-120 mins | # Flags 120-180 mins | # Flags 180-240 mins | # Flags >= 240 mins |
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-01-01 | 3,072             | 4,687               | 2,540                | 1,849                | 9,582               |
| 2016-02-01 | 850               | 2,227               | 1,305                | 1,129                | 11,563              |
| 2016-03-01 | 3,328             | 4,461               | 2,294                | 1,712                | 10,245              |
| 2016-04-01 | 1,741             | 3,079               | 2,146                | 1,657                | 10,167              |
| 2016-05-01 | 1,611             | 3,664               | 2,789                | 2,302                | 11,148              |
| 2016-06-01 | 2,135             | 4,066               | 2,395                | 1,717                | 9,087               |
| 2016-07-01 | 1,248             | 3,282               | 2,053                | 1,821                | 11,404              |
| 2016-08-01 | 1,365             | 3,047               | 2,277                | 1,838                | 11,123              |
| 2016-09-01 | 1,271             | 2,675               | 1,630                | 1,374                | 11,821              |
| 2016-10-01 | 910               | 1,735               | 1,015                | 808                  | 10,089              |
| 2016-11-01 | 2,367             | 2,799               | 1,425                | 966                  | 7,671               |
| 2016-12-01 | 4,368             | 3,295               | 1,351                | 846                  | 2,315               |
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Total      | 24,266            | 39,017              | 23,220               | 18,019               | 116,215             |
+------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

From this we can see that in 2016:

- most flags took a substantially long time to be processed - over 240 minutes
- since the last election, we've had a large drop in flags lingering in the queue, but we've seen a steady increase in flags being processed in under 60 minutes.

But who is processing the flags at each time frame? The moderators or the review queue?

Over the past year, the **LQRQ processed 108,434 VLQ & NAA flags** ([visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ASon.png)), of these

- **7,362 flags** were handled within 60 minutes,
- **8,378 flags** were reviewed in 60 to 120 minutes,
- **7,905 flags** were processed in 120 to 180 minutes,
- it took 180 to 240 minutes to process **7,544 flags**,
- and it took 4+ hours (240+ minutes) to complete review on **77,245 flags**

By comparison, the **Moderators handled 112,303 VLQ & NAA flags** ([visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rdzB.png)) that were also in review, of these

- **16,904 flags** were processed in less than 60 minutes,
- **30,639 flags** were handled in 60 to 120 minutes,
- **15,315 flags** were cleared in 120 to 180 minutes,
- **10,475 flags** were processed 180 to 240 minutes after the flag was in review,
- and it took 240+ minutes to process **38,970 flags** that were also in review

#### Some takeaways:

- There is a pretty even split between the LQRQ and the moderators when processing flags that hit review
- Moderators tend to process similar numbers of review flags in any of the timespans (< 60, 60-120, etc), but the LQRQ takes significantly longer to process flags with most of them being handled > 4 hours into review

We already know that the review queue is pretty much handling all it can handle. We're going to look to see if there are anything we can do to tweak the settings, on it to help things move along. Keep an eye out in the coming weeks for [another test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science) for science.

Comment: I was thinking if it was possible a matrix of amount of flags and reviews(reviewers) per time of the day. It could be that flag and reviewers aren't active at the same time (ie. flags are casted around 00:00UTC while reviewers are waking up later).

Comment: BTW, do the amount of reviews modify the order on the mod queue? (more reviews = higher on the queue when it passes?)

Comment: @Braiam no flags are presented in order by flag date.

Comment: would be interesting to find out how close reviewers judgement is to that of moderators by studying how moderators handled flags that already had some reviews (not enough to drop them before moderator intervenes) and comparing decision of moderators to that of reviewers

Comment: @gnat my principal interest is that community handle more flags (ergo moderators handling less).

Comment: my interest is the same @Braiam - though currently it is primarily based on an expectation that reviewers judgement is close enough to that of moderators. I would like to check that expectation, maybe there is a substantial difference in which case I would have to reconsider

Comment: @gnat On items that have started to be reviewed, the mods and the community are aligned about 92% of the time.

Comment: thanks @bluefeet - feels like it would be safe to give LQ reviewers a bit more time to complete reviews before passing the buck to mods. Have you considered giving them an hour or two more than they have now?

Comment: @gnat I'm looking at various options.  We'll probably do a bit of testing again soon.