# Front page criteria

Tags: support, questions, front-page

By what criteria are questions featured on the front page? There are plenty questions in the "Questions" tab that cannot be found on the front page, many of which seem quite good, while new user, low quality questions frequently find their way there.

I suspect details might not be something for the public knowledge, but I would like to hear as much as possible on this matter. Is this based on user question history or algorithmically calculated quality of the question? Such information would help some users ask better questions.

Answer (score 15):

The front page is [heavily cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114294/why-havent-my-edits-been-bumping-questions/114713#114713), which might also indicate why you can't find the questions immediately.

Some of the information you're looking for is described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage). Basically, every new question is run through some algorithm to determine potential problems with it; if the question fails, it will be withheld from the homepage until it is reviewed in Triage.

This might not be the entire story; it makes sense that a user's question history also plays a role.

> Such information would help some users ask better questions.

I disagree with you on this point, though. It will only help people writing questions that pass the filter more easily.

Comment: This is assuming the ill will of users, but perhaps you are right, there are always people that do not want to learn