# How do I flag questions that I believe are useful only to their authors?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I've seen a lot of terrible questions while reviewing Triage and browsing the tags and such. But I don't know how to flag some of these questions. I've included examples for clarification.

I'm asking this because I'm sick of looking for questions to answer and just seeing a bunch of junk that's asking how to set up a system, how to use a compiler, how to fix the entire source of a program, why there's a segmentation fault, etc. Nobody really wants to answer these and they don't contribute to the community at all.

- ["plz send teh codez"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475693/twos-complement-method-for-signed-integers) questions (asking people to write code w/o any effort)
- A [complete code dump asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474697/udp-client-doesnt-receive-anything-from-server-in-c) for help, 50+ lines long, completely useless to the community. These types of posts would be useful if they included a specific part of the offending code instead of every source file in their project. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474408/program-crashes-after-pressing-enter-warnings-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472998/segmentation-fault-splitting-command-into-tokens), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471488/how-to-fetch-the-3-bits-field-from-the-below-mentioned-string-format), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474879/c-lynda-com-tutorial-files-not-compiling-in-terminal-or-eclipse)... they're all over.
- [Close enough to an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472130/this-code-not-gives-the-file-first-value-which-is-a) but still just "this program doesn't do what I want it to"
- [Not really about the language tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476015/gcc-wall-myfile-c-myfile), more about a system/compiler

Is this last type of question on-topic at all? It seems to me like it won't really be much help to any future readers.

These types of questions don't do much for other users, only the OPs.
So what flags should I use (if any)?

Comment: I like that in an item referring to a lack of effort, it was decided that the word "without" was too much trouble to write out in full `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - "plz send teh codez" questions (asking people to write code w/o any effort)

Unclear/Too Broad

> - A complete code dump asking for help, 50+ lines long, completely useless to the community. These types of posts would be useful if they included a specific part of the offending code instead of every source file in their project. Examples here, here, here, here... they're all over.

Missing MCVE

> - Close enough to an MCVE but still just "this program doesn't do what I want it to"

Still missing MCVE

> - Not really about programming, more about a system/compiler (I'm looking for a better example)

Looks OK. Makefiles and make are about programming.

Comment: Yeah, the system/compiler one wasn't a very good example. I'll edit my post and then add some more in the comments.

Comment: All right, I updated it with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476015/gcc-wall-myfile-c-myfile) link.

Comment: @MDXF I'd appreciate non moving targets! But that question still is more or less OK. Probably a duplicate, or also missing a MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Do you think the fourth type of question is on-topic?

Comment: _"Do you think the fourth type of question is on-topic?"_ Not really.

Comment: Well there's got to be *some* flag for them then...

Comment: @MDXF As mentioned in my previous comment: Missing MCVE

Comment: Ah! Sorry, didn't catch that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> - ["plz send teh codez"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475693/twos-complement-method-for-signed-integers) questions (asking people to write code w/o any effort)

This isn't asking for code, so it's *not* a code request. It might be a duplicate, and it could certainly benefit from a better title (which I've provided) - if I couldn't quickly find a duplicate, I would simply answer "Requires Editing" in Triage.

> - A [complete code dump asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474697/udp-client-doesnt-receive-anything-from-server-in-c) for help, 50+ lines long, completely useless to the community. These types of posts would be useful if they included a specific part of the offending code instead of every source file in their project. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474408/program-crashes-after-pressing-enter-warnings-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472998/segmentation-fault-splitting-command-into-tokens), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471488/how-to-fetch-the-3-bits-field-from-the-below-mentioned-string-format), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474879/c-lynda-com-tutorial-files-not-compiling-in-terminal-or-eclipse)... they're all over.

As πάντα ῥεῖ notes, the correct action here is to choose close, Off Topic, and select

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself...

...of course, you'll want to be at least reasonably certain that the question *doesn't* contain those three things (desired behavior, specific problem, shortest code necessary). In particular, a big chunk of code isn't a show-stopper if the asker actually takes the time to describe what the code is supposed to do and where it's going wrong; the problems arise when the explanation is insufficient for the code being presented.

Note also that questions complaining about null pointer dereferencing are quite often duplicates of a great number of questions that have answers explaining how to debug these; if you can keep a few links handy, that might save you some time.

> - [Close enough to an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472130/this-code-not-gives-the-file-first-value-which-is-a) but still just "this program doesn't do what I want it to"

This question is unclear. You could also use the MVCE off-topic reason, but "unclear" is fewer clicks. In theory, a reasonably lucky person could probably guess at what the asker is asking and edit that question into shape, but I personally wouldn't bet on "Requires Editing" finding that person.

> - [Not really about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476015/gcc-wall-myfile-c-myfile), more about a system/compiler

I don't know many people who use GCC for things other than programming. The question is unclear, but realistically it could be edited into a clear question without too much effort; I'd probably go with "Requires Editing" for expediency, though no one would fault you for choosing "Unclear".

Comment: What I meant by 'not about programming' was 'not about the language it was tagged as'. Correct, questions about gcc are technically also about c but I think they shouldn't be tagged c.

Comment: They frequently are though. Retagging is always appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

The appropriate flag would be "Very Low Quality", but since it almost never results in any action being taken, and has a [bizarro-world interaction with Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323946/603977) that removes any teeth the flag might have even in theory, there's no flag that is actually effective for garbage questions.

The best you can do is downvote, vote to close (given the privilege), and then try to forget about it because the chances of it actually being dealt with are slim to nil.

Comment: "the chances of it actually being dealt with are slim to nil" I agree, I've had a lot of edits and flags rejected because it seemed like it just wasn't important to reviewers... That's why I'm asking, what flags can I use so it's more noticeable?

Comment: I wish I had a better answer, but I simply don't think that any flag is going to make a difference.

Comment: The original intention was for VLQ to result in instant deletion. Unfortunately, folks got in the habit of using it for everything... Hence the bizarre interaction with Triage, which is now responsible for... well, *triaging* VLQ flags. So a VLQ flag in Triage would be a wee bit pointless.

Comment: @JoshCaswell All right, think there's any way to draw attention to them then? Could this be problem with our diamond users?

Comment: So you think the appropriate way to handle a question in the Triage queue is to flag it as needing to be sent to Triage?

Comment: The problem I see, @Shog9, is that the path to resolution (deletion) through Triage is _longer_ than it would be if no-one had flagged it as VLQ in the first place.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The path is the same.  Get 5 close votes and 3 delete votes.  Triage doesn't really help, but it doesn't hurt (unless triage mis-handles it, which, granted, is a real risk).  Of course, this means that if you can vote to close you should do that, not flag as VLQ, and if you don't, you should flag for a close reason, so it'll get to the close queue, rather than flagging it as VLQ so someone else can flag it for closure to send it to the close queue.

Comment: The shortest path is always: 1) have the privilege to just close / delete / edit, 2) use that privilege, @Josh. All of the flags, all of the queues, all of the pomp and ceremony... Pretty much just make that longer. But they also make it accessible to more people. I think I described them as "training wheels for moderators" somewhere once, and I don't mean that in a pejorative way: the intent is to guide folks who want to help toward actually being able to do so.

Comment: Neither of these comments make any argument against my point. If I should always prefer to close instead of flagging, why does the flag exist? If the point of the queues is just to get moderation training, why would I want to raise a flag? Flags are how I'm supposed to be able to get help dealing with situations that I can't handle on my own, including situations where waiting for two days and eight votes to remove a garbage post is a waste of everyone's time and effort. Something has gone off the rails with this mechanism.