# If this isn’t a low quality “question”, how low would quality have to be?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

My VLQ flag on this “question” was declined:

[Sample question to test out the StackExchange API website deal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60816620/341994)

It says:

> Sample text:
>
> Hey guys. As you may have already heard we will be working remotely for now.
>
> But please make sure your productivity doesn’t go down. Keep working on your learning your profile and the interview questions. And work on the stack overflow project if you haven’t finished it.

Declined? Really? Really? The quality of this as a question is zero. It’s not a question at all. It’s not even intended as a question. It’s just occupying needless bandwidth. It even says, “Hi there, I’m occupying needless bandwidth.”

What does it take? I ask you.

Comment: Yep, that is nonsensical. Maybe just close the question though - there is no value in handling the answer independently.

Comment: @halfer But now there’s a Declined mark against me. Why? I was right to call this to attention of the moderators.  “I have done the state some service, and they know it.”

Comment: Ah yes, fair enough. I agree.

Comment: While I agree that a VLQ flag shouldn't have been declined, raising such a flag on a question is basically useless and *much* less effective than *voting to close*. Your VLQ flag just puts the question into the Triage queue, where it's looked at by, nominally, 3 users, who are asked to determine if it's "Unsalvageable" (i.e. should be closed, or is spam / rude/abusive), or "Requires Editing" (i.e. put it in the Help & Improvement queue). An "Unsalvageable (close)" result puts it in the Close-Vote review queue, which you could have done by just casting a close-vote. A CV would have been faster.

Comment: I think that the mods generally want the VLQ flag to be used for straight up gibberish, as this one has enough real words to make someone have to read it to decide it should be deleted. As Shog said: "VLQ flags on questions that should be closed just create unnecessary overhead - someone else has to spend more time thinking about why the question needs to be closed because you didn't specify." [(source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/7795130) However, this question still meets the baseline of "obvious, unarguable garbage," so I wouldn't have declined the flag.

Comment: @Makyen I was hoping for more than closure. But in any case, that’s not why I’m here; I would like the declined mark against me lifted.

Comment: @DavyM Gibberish is exactly what it is. It is Lorem Ipsum by another name.

Comment: This is another case where I wonder why the Very Low Quality flag even exists.

Comment: @matt More than closure is closing and deleting, or spam / rude/abusive. You have the ability to both close-vote and delete-vote. If the post doesn't qualify as spam or rude/abusive, close-voting, down-voting, and delete-voting are your tools for accomplishing "more than closure". A VLQ flag doesn't even come close to accomplishing "more than closure". A VLQ flag is less than a close-vote. If you really think something should be directly handled by elected moderators, you need to raise a custom mod-flag and explain the situation and why it's something which should be handled directly by mods.

Comment: @Makyen That's fair enough; it may be that I just don't have a correct mental picture of what happens when you designate something as VLQ.

Comment: It's a problem the network  has with very narrow and prescriptive labels that would mean something to any reasonable person, but have a different and very specific meaning according to the site's rules. It's mostly bad UI and horrible UX. _"Not an answer"_, _"Requires editing"_ and _"Very low quality"_ come to mind. Neither of these mean what you would think without many hours of SO life, and this leads to countless clashes.

Comment: Other than that, a declined flag does not count against you in any meaningful way (unless you are getting several declined in a relatively short span of time). That being said, I agree that it kinda hurts. AFAIK, mods can't "undecline" a declined flag.

Comment: related: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Comment: Basically, take how much effort people used to have to make in order to ask a question here, double it, and that's how much effort it takes to get rid of crap like the above "question". /s

Comment: on a gneral note, it looks like questions having ["coronavirus"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+coronavirus) and ["covid"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+covid) could benefit from a thorough cleanup

Comment: @Makyen You say that the VLQ flag just puts the question into a triage queue. But that is not what the Declined message says; it says "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it." Therefore I conclude that a human being with authority declared authoritatively that the question is fine.

Comment: @yivi I don't agree that a declined flag "does not count against you". My experience is that it causes a banner to appear whenever you flag or even when you do a review queue, and right now I am barred from review queues (that is in fact what led me to examine my review history).

Comment: Being barred from review queues is completely unrelated to flagging. And the banner does not mean anything if you do not get more declined flags in a relatively short timespan. Just to be a bit more careful.

Comment: @yivi Well then I don't understand the bar. When I click on the review queue icon I see "There are no review queues available to you." But I haven't been told why. I didn't fail any "tests" (as far as I can remember, of course that's not Evidence for anything). Is there a way to find out what the charge is, or is this just one of those Kafka-esque situations?

Comment: If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/review, you do not get any message about the review suspension?

Comment: But anyway, it's related to reviews such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25646293). "Requires editing" was not a good choice there. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving) for more details, for example. Also, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work) if you want to spend your time in Triage. Personally, I wouldn't recommend it. It's not a very useful review queue IMO.

Comment: @yivi Yes!!! Thank you. Yes, it says "Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25646293 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better shape." Of course I don't agree; in my view, that question _was_ salvageable by editing. It just had some formatting problems but it was a real answer. Someone else marked it as unsalvageable, but that doesn't make it the only correct assessment, surely.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with you there. That question needed to be closed, and no editing by a third party would have saved it from that fate.

Comment: @yivi You could be totally right, but I don't quite see why a voluntary form of assistance where one is asked to register one's opinion turns into a punishment. My assessment might benefit from another opinion, but it _got_ another opinion and no harm done. This is just another case of being Burned by the Sun, I guess.

Comment: Because it's not "punishment". It's just stopping you from volunteering where the result of your effort is not the desirable one, so you can see how to better spend that effort for better results. Here, reviewing poorly is not only a waste of your time, but a waste of other volunteer's time. You are momentarily blocked from performing work for free so you can get better acquainted with the rules, and your working for free is more effective in the future.

Comment: I'll repost a comment I left earlier regarding this: Imagine a person tries to volunteer to a meat-space organization. And during their volunteering they end up hindering the organization work instead of helping it, doing things wrong and creating more work for other volunteers. One would expect this person would be told off, right? That way they can learn that they are not contributing effectively and can change their approach. Well, it's exactly the same with review.

Comment: @yivi ok I can accept that :)

Comment: Personally if I were to flag such a question I would probably have chosen "rude/abusive". It's clearly abusing the ability to post questions.

Comment: I'd say the mod misclicked.

Comment: @Makyen Your first comment here seems like a fully general argument against ever using the VLQ flag on questions in any circumstances. Is that your intended message - that it's simply a useless flag type best never used (on questions)? If not, in what circumstance *would* it make sense to use?

Comment: [_"The appropriate flag would be 'Very Low Quality', but since it almost never results in any action being taken, and has a bizarro-world interaction with Triage that removes any teeth the flag might have even in theory, there's no flag that is actually effective for garbage questions."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337588)

Comment: There used to be a flag "not a real question" which covered a lot of cases, now long gone, alas.

Comment: "Not a real question" was a close reason, not a flag. This is, in my opinion, an ideal use-case for the "very low quality" flag. I feel strongly that your flag was correct. I've disagreed with the moderator who declined your flag on these same grounds before. The reality is that VLQ flags on questions are a bit of a roulette game, depending on which moderator sees your flag. If it were me, I'd keep raising them, but I don't obsess over statistics like declined flags.