# Why is the flag "very low quality" only available for some questions?

Tags: support

I was reviewing the First Posts queue, and I saw that sometimes I could flag a *question* as "very low quality". As far as I remember, this is always available for *answers*, and for a while I thought it never was for questions. But now I've seen it as an alternative for questions too, but only sometimes and I cannot see any pattern.

Please clarify this for me.

Comment: Related: [Fixing the disconnect between VLQ and Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323946/603977)