# Require accounts to be "established" for a few days before they are allowed to ask a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

There is no question that the quality of questions is a huge problem on the main site. With the recent loss of a substantial number of moderators due to recent events, it has only gotten worse. Many users (including myself) haven't helped the situation by attempting to answer bad questions (usually in an attempt to earn some rep) instead of closing them.

A couple different methods have been proposed to fix this [including rep requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253168/7886229). However, contentions including attempting to bypass it by creating multiple accounts have rightfully (imo) shutdown that proposal.

Instead, I propose an account age requirement. What I mean by this is that in order for someone to post a question their account must be at least lets say 48 hours old. This has been attempted on many other internet platforms including some subreddits (not saying we are reddit, just suggesting this idea isn't radical).

I think this could help for a couple reasons. Many of the bad posts are as I say *trigger posts*. Someone new to a language has an issue, searches it up, finds Stack Overflow and immediately posts without looking at rules or anything. This would prevent these types of posts. Many of the poor posts are from very new users. This may help solve that.

People may argue that this might not solve this issue but only delay it. People will create the account wait the time period and then post their crappy question. This maybe true. I am really not sure. Maybe we can test it out for a couple weeks and see what happens like we have done with other features.

If you do agree on at least testing out this idea, what time period would you suggest? I think 48 hours might be good because it is long enough to prevent *trigger posts* while not too long that a people will be discouraged from joining.

I want to hear the community thoughts. I apologize if this has been proposed before, I wasn't able to find it from some Googling so I thought I would ask.

**I would like to emphasize obviously this will NOT solve the issue of older users posting bad questions. But it might help solve the issue of new users posting bad questions. They are two different issues. This might help solve one.**

---

I'd also like to argue that this is inline and in fact reinforces Stack Overflow's core ideas as a Wiki for the community not for the individual. The urgency of a new users issue isn't really relevant to the community, having a new user wait some time before posting I don't think hurts the community much. Important and good questions will be asked eventually so that won't change.

---

**Heres the stats**:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1162974

`avg` doesn't seem to be working properly but by just scrolling through, you can see that most of the posts have low or zero scores.

After downloading the CSV and running an average on that I got an average of 0.2614 for 2019. This in my opinion is low. As opposed to 1.3 in 2014.

Comment: You have, unfortunately, not identified the correct root cause of low-quality questions. They aren't all coming from newly registered users.

Comment: @CodyGray That is very true. However many of them do. This will help solve the new user issue. This isn't supposed to solve all low quality questions. That is impossible but I really think we can reduce by implementing this. Again, I don't know. Maybe we can test it out and see.

Comment: If we do a bit of SEDE... can we point that the average score or "new account's first question" is lower than the rest? Cause... I'd look at that first. If the number is lower for newer accounts... maybe we need this yes. If it isn't.... then no

Comment: @Patrice Yes. I am looking for the page to this. Definitively a good idea.

Comment: As a long-time contributor to Stack Overflow, I still ask very low quality questions by the standards of this community. If I'm unable to word my question well today, just waiting 2 more days isn't going to help.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Again, I am trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: What's the average of user questions asked in 2019 by accounts older than 2 days?

Comment: @DaveS https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1162994 About 1.1

Comment: That's not what I got https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1163028/average-score-of-posts-created-within-two-days-of-user-creation-date-in-2019

Comment: @DaveS You are better at querying than me. Yours is correct.

Comment: Bad questions are bad questions no matter who wrote them. In fact, most questions are bad when they are first posed. It takes editing and reediting to get them into a form that is understandable and concise yet still conveys all the information necessary for the problem at hand. Blocking new users from asking question will just discourage them from engaging in this process to learn how to craft good questions.

Comment: I think that the intention behind this -- avoiding "trigger questions" as you call them -- is spot-on. My worry is that blocking a user from asking a question won't sufficiently guide them towards better understanding the community before posting; they'll just post their trigger question elsewhere and forget about SO. And then when they have a new trigger question next week, they'll be able to post it. So, even though this is definitely moving in the right direction (for which I give this question an upvote), I agree with the others that it's not getting to the root of the problem.

Comment: Feel sorry for you that you wrote this on Meta -- hang around for a while to see what people dislike.

Comment: @JL2210 Thanks? I am not sure where else I should have asked.

Comment: @JBis Well, anywhere. In general people don't like restricting new users for various reasons that I'm not going to go to here. I've seen users that have only had an account for an hour write great questions and users that have been here since I was 4 write crappy questions.

Comment: Meta is the correct place to ask, and we’re all ears for proposals/suggestions to increase the quality of questions. However, I (and apparently others) don’t think this is a good idea because it doesn’t solve the core problem and has other unfortunate side effects. Note that votes on Meta often act as a proxy for conveniently and democratically expressing an opinion, so they shouldn’t be taken to imply that there is anything materially wrong with your question or its presentation.

Comment: JBis I think @JL2210 suggests "not to propose features if you can't handle if people disagreeing with your proposal" (also I don't see any reason why - there is no *visible* indication that you are unhappy with people expressing opinions not aligned with your own)

Answer (score 4):

> With the recent loss of a substantial number of moderators due to recent events, it has only gotten worse.

A *substantial number* is ... pretty much up to interpretation. Without numbers this is pure speculation. Fact is, that question quality (if measured by upvotes / closevotes) is decreasing.

> Many users (including myself) haven't helped the situation by attempting to answer bad questions (usually in an attempt to earn some rep) instead of closing them.

Hopefully [Megan's birthday present](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good) will help reducing the number of these answers. That might also have a positive impact on the questions asked.

> Instead, I propose an account age requirement.

I fear that this will lead to more good questions to be forgotten ...

I think the *questions* have to get more mature, not the accounts asking them. It would be way more effective to slow down the *process of asking*, e.g. by introducing a second step to reread the question (which was added already).

Comment: Putting numbers to the moderator situation, if I recall correctly, SO itself only lost 2 or 3--which is stressful for other moderators sure, but not what I would call a substantial number considering SO had like 20, I think. A substantial amount would probably be more like 10.

Comment: @Chipster 4 mods resigned from SO, at least 3 suspended their activity, and 1 mod also stepped down for unrelated reasons. It’s been a fairly noticeable loss, especially considering that several of us who remain are also quite busy with jobs and Real Life, reducing the amount of time we have to handle flags. SO gets an absurd number of flags. SO Meta alone is larger than most of the other SE sites.

Comment: @CodyGray I stand corrected. I was only aware of Jon and Robert Harvey. I must have missed some others. Revisiting [the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/476201), as it turns out I was very wrong...